# Diferença entre object, dynamic e var

Tags: c#

Estou realizando alguns testes e pelo que me parece **object** e **dynamic** realizam a mesma tarefa ao contrário de **var** que depois de atribuído é impossível mudar seu tipo, qual a diferença entre eles?

```
var variavel = 15; // É preciso atribuir um valor, se não não compila, não aceita iniciar como NULL;
object objeto = 15;
dynamic dinamico = 15;

Console.WriteLine(variavel.GetType().ToString()); // Int
Console.WriteLine(objeto.GetType().ToString()); // Int
Console.WriteLine(dinamico.GetType().ToString()); // Int

variavel = "Teste"; // Não deixa atribuir
objeto = "Teste";
dinamico = "Teste";

Console.WriteLine(variavel.GetType().ToString()); // Int
Console.WriteLine(objeto.GetType().ToString()); // String
Console.WriteLine(dinamico.GetType().ToString()); // String
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Fiz uma resposta bem detalhada e exaustiva... se tiver mais alguma dúvida, fique a vontade para perguntar. =D

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## object

Refere-se ao tipo `System.Object` que é a base para todos os outros tipos,
sejam eles tipos-referência ou tipo-valor.

Uma variável/parâmetro desse tipo permite que se associe qualquer tipo de dados,
sendo que se for uma classe,
ocorre uma atribuição simples, e se for um tipo-valor, ocorre primeiro o boxing desse valor,
e depois uma atribuição.

Além disso, há tratamento especial para tipos nullable
(`Nullable<TStruct>`, no C# podendo ser representados por `TStruct?`), em que,
se o nullable `.HasValue` for falso, o valor é considerado `null`, caso contrário,
o valor contido no nullable é boxed e então é feita a operação de atribuição.

```
object x = 1; // vai ocorrer boxing do valor 1, pois Int32 é um value-type
object y = "str"; // não vai haver boxing, pois String é uma reference-type
// nullable é value-type, mas nunca será boxed dentro de um object
int? i = null;
int? j = 10;
object z1 = i; // z1 será null
object z2 = j; // z2 terá um Int32 com o valor 10 boxed e atribuido à variável
```

## var

Isso é o que se chama de *[açucar-sintático](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)*.
É só uma palavra chave que é usada para que o compilador adivinhe o tipo na hora de compilar.
Isso se chama inferência de tipo. Vou ser direto:

```
var x = 1;
var y = "str";
var z = x == 2 ? new MeuObjeto("xpto") : new MeuObject("abc");
```

será traduzido pelo compilador para:

```
Int32 x = 1;
String y = "str";
MeuObjeto z = x == 2 ? new MeuObjeto("xpto") : new MeuObject("abc");
```

**Quando `var` é a única opção?**

Existe um uso em que `var` não é apenas açucar-sintático.
A grande sacada nessa inferência de tipo, são os tipos anônimos, ou seja,
tipos que são criados inline, e que não possuem nome:

```
var a = new { Nome = "Miguel" };
```

Não existe tradução em C# para isso. Mas na hora de compilar,
o C# vai gerar um tipo instantaneamente, e usá-lo:

```
<Projection>f__0 a = new <Projection>f__0 { Nome = "Miguel" };
```

Sendo gerada uma classe `<Projection>f__0`, perfeitamente válida!

## dynamic

Essa é uma palavra chave que permite chamar métodos e propriedades de um objeto qualquer,
sem conhecer o seu tipo. Isso é conhecido como *[late-binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)*, ou seja, é associar a
chamada ao método/propriedade de destino somente no momento em que a chamada for feita.

Note que, ao fazer o dispatch, será usado um dispatcher que age exatamente como o C#
(ou o Visual Basic, se estiver usando dynamic no VB). Esse dispatcher tenta localizar o
método/propriedade/operação da mesma forma que o C# faria... e se falhar será lançada uma
exceção indicando que a chamada não poderá ser feita.

Procure saber mais sobre *[duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)*, pois o conceito é muito semelhante...
senão o mesmo.

**Performance do `dynamic`**

Mas não ache que você vai perder rios de performance fazendo isso,
pois **a implementação de uma chamada sobre um `dynamic` é muito eficiente**.
No ponto exato em que é feita a chamada,
é compilado uma chamada a um objeto estático que faz cache do método a ser chamado em
um dicionário de tipos. Isso quer dizer que a chamada só é lenta da primeira vez para cada tipo,
mas da segunda vez que for executado o mesmo código com o mesmo tipo, será muito mais rápido.

Refere-se a essa chamada como *call-site*.
Note que uma linha de código pode conter vários call-sites, um para cada operação sendo feita:

```
// existem 2 call-sites na linha abaixo:
// - uma para a propriedade Length,
// - e outro para o type-cast para int
int a = (int)dyn.Length;
```

**`dynamic` não é um tipo**

`dynamic` não é um tipo, mas sim, uma palavra chave que determina uma forma diferente de fazer
dispatch (escolha de que método/propriedade será chamada de fato)... para se ter um paralelo,
herança e polimorfismo são duas outras formas de fazer dispatch,
diferentes daquela feita quando `dynamic` é usado.

Apesar de não ser um tipo, *existem tipos que são associados à palavra chave `dynamic`.
Esses tipos fazem parte da DLR ([Dynamic Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd233052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))*

**Referência:**

- [Understanding the Dynamic Keyword in C# 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx): explica a diferença entre as palavras chaves, além de fazer introdução à DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime)
- [Dynamic Dispatch – How dynamic work in C#](http://blog.alxandr.me/2013/07/26/dynamic-dispatch-how-dynamic-work-in-c/): explica como é feita a chamada a métodos/propriedades e operadores quando usando `dynamic`, e porque é quase tão rápido quando usar o próprio método compilado
- [C# Dynamic - dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic) - artigo do dotnetperls, mostrando mais detalhes sobre `dynamic`. Achei interessante a análise da forma que o C# gera os call-sites.
- [Visão geral do Dynamic Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd233052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Conversões boxing e unboxing (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yz2be5wk.aspx): sobre boxing e unboxing
- [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)
- [How Duck Typing Benefits C# Developers - Phill Haack - sobre duck typing](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/19/why-duck-typing-matters-to-c-developers.aspx/) (esse cara é f0d@)
- [Tipos anônimos (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397696.aspx)
- [Can't return anonymous type from method? Really?](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx/) - como são implementados tipos anônimos pelo C#

Comment: Duck-typing não necessáriamente involve tipagem ou dispatch dinámico. Em C++, nos templates, a conferência é feita em tempo de compilação e usando tipagem estática.

Comment: No C# só há a opção de duck-typing com dispatch dinâmico, sendo que o destino da chamada fica em um mapa, dentro de um campo estático que representa cada uma das chamadas feitas sobre `dynamic` no código. A isso se deu o nome de *Call-Site*.

Comment: Estava me referindo a duck-typing em templates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#Templates_or_generic_types

Answer (score 11):

O tipo `object` é o tipo pai de todos os demais tipos em .NET. É por esse motivo que você pode usar uma variável do tipo `object` para apontar ou guardar todo tipo de informação em .NET. A quem tiver dúvidas sobre o porquê disso, sugiro estudar dois tópicos de *orientação a objetos*: *herança* e *polimorfismo*.

Se você utiliza a palavra reservada `var` para criar uma variável, ela será tipada estaticamente. O tipo que a variável terá será decidido pelo restante do código - o compilador se responsabiliza por determinar o tipo mais apropriado.

Se você utiliza a palavra reservada `dynamic` o comportamento é similar ao de `object`, mas **nenhuma verificação de tipo é feita em tempo de compilação.** ([fonte: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)). Isso significa que quaisquer erros por chamadas ou atribuições inválidas não serão detectados antes do programa ser construído. Se tais erros passarem batidos pelo compilador, poderão se manifestar em tempo de execução.

A palavra reservada `dynamic` realmente parece não ter sentido em um mundo puramente .NET, no qual você poderia talvez desligar avisos e erros do compilador em certos casos. Porém pode ser útil quando você vai integrar .NET com alguma outra plataforma, ou quando utilizamos C# em conjunto com linguagens de tipagem dinâmica como *Iron Python* (isso é citado na fonte que usei acima).

Comment: `var` não é fortemente tipado, como qualquer outro tipo em C# (uma linguagem fracamente tipada), graças a polimorfismo e casting. O correto é dizer que `var` cria uma variável estaticamente tipada, ou tipada em tempo de compilação.

Comment: @Mephy tem razão. Vou editar, valeu pela dica.

Comment: @Mephy,o C# não seria fortemente tipado ao invés de fracamente tipada ?

Answer (score 3):

Vou ser bem coloquial:

- `dynamic` é uma aberração que a Microsoft criou para atender ao mundo web e as REST API's, é como se fosse um tipo variante no C# que pode receber um objeto de qualquer tipo. Por que aberração? **Pois é um tipo não seguro (type-unsafe) dentro de uma liguagem que se diz type-safe**.
- `var` é uma facilidade para escrever e determina que o compilador no momento de compilação vai determinar qual será o tipo com base no primeiro valor que o objeto recebeu.
- `object` é o **nada** e **tudo** ao mesmo tempo. Basicamente tudo deriva de object, mas na programação se vc quiser usá-lo será necessário testar e converter no tipo de objeto que se deseja...

Recomendo que leia os livros de programação básica em C#, gostei muito dos da Wrox (C# for Begginers)

Comment: "mas na programação se vc quiser usá-lo será necessário testar e converter no tipo de objeto que se deseja..." Se tudo que você quer é ler o hash ou o tipo de um objeto, `object` é bem conveniente e dispensa `cast`s ou outras manipulações de tipo.

Comment: Sim, concordo e acho que foram raros os casos em que eu testei o tipo de um objeto para não usá-lo. O uso de `object` é muito comum quando vamos usar apenas as funções padrões `.ToString()`, `.GetHashCode()`, `.GetType()`

Answer (score 3):

```
public sealed class Exemplo()
{
     private String _nome;

     public Exemplo(String nome)
     {    
          _nome = nome
     }

     public String Nome
     {
          get { return (String)_nome; }
          internal set { _nome = (Object)value; }
     }

     public String NomeInvertido
     {
          get 
          {
             var ex = new Exemplo(_nome); //Boa hora para você usar var, você sabe que new Exemplo(String) gera um objeto do tipo Exemplo. Você está dentro da própria classe.
             ex.Inverte();
             return ex.Nome;
          }
     }

     private void Inverte()
     {
          Char[] letras = _nome.ToCharArray();
          String inverso = String.Empty;
          for (Int32 i = letras.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
               inverso += letras[i];
          _nome = inverso;
     }
}

Exemplo explicito = new Exemplo("Guilherme");
//Object exemplo = new Exemplo("Guilherme");
var implicito = new Exemplo("Guilherme");
dynamic dinamico = new Exemplo("Guilherme");

//SUCESSO:
Console.WriteLine(explicito.Nome); //Guilherme
Console.WriteLine(implicito.Nome); //Guilherme
Console.WriteLine(dinamico.Nome); //Guilherme

//Acessando um método Private
explicito.Inverte(); //Método não é público. Não pode ser acessado daqui.
implicito.Inverte(); //Método não é público. Não pode ser acessado daqui.
dinamico.Inverte(); //Não vai dar problema na hora de compilar, porem no momento que você executar esse código vai gerar uma exceção.

dinamico.Sobrenome; //Não existe esta propriedade porem só vai descobrir isso depois de executar a aplicação. Digamos que você utilize uma DLL externa, e a classe Exemplo está nessa DLL, hoje você não tem essa propriedade, mas amanhã você atualiza essa DLL e essa propriedade irá existir sem problemas...
```