# Quando usar var em C#?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, declaração-de-variável

Em C#, variáveis locais no escopo de um método podem ser [declaradas com tipo implícito usando `var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), e o tipo é resolvido em tempo de compilação:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; // explicitly typed
```

<sup>Exemplo da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)</sup>

Casos de uso de tipos anônimos chegam a exigir o `var`, como já mencionado [numa resposta aqui do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12737). Porém, nos casos em que ele é opcional, a escolha é puramente uma questão de estilo? Existem recomendações (oficiais ou não, contanto que justificadas) para se utilizar ou evitar o `var` em determinadas situações?

Comment: Eu diria para usar *sempre*, a menos que exista uma boa razão em contrário, mas é só minha opinião. Como comentei em uma [outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21512/215), eu enxergo a declaração de tipo como um meta-dado, útil em alguns casos mas em geral desnecessário (as variáveis idealmente devem ser auto-explicativas - tanto pelo nome escolhido, quanto pelo contexto). No mais, não tenho experiência suficiente em C# para uma resposta bem fundamentada.

Comment: Pelas respostas atuais, *sempre* é um pouco de exagero, mas é bem próximo disso mesmo. Engraçado que eu achava que fosse o contrário. Como uso principalmente linguagens dinâmicas, achava que linguagens de tipagem estática praticamente exigiam tipificação explícita, e que qualquer coisa diferente disso seria mal vista. Ponto pro C#.

Comment: Sempre que possível (se é possível inferir é possível usar var). Exceto por casos específicos: Você precisa de uma referência de carro, mas o objeto atribuído é pickup.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Existem situações em que uma das duas formas é "exigida" e em outras que, antecipando a resposta longa, é uma questão de gosto.

E só para deixar claro que estamos falando de variáveis locais, não de campos da estrutura que devem ter seus tipos explícitos sempre (assim como dos parâmetros). Há debate se isto deveria mudar ou não. Há dificuldades na implantação.

## LINQ

Quando o [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) está sendo usado é comum selecionar alguns campos de informação como é feito no SQL e o retorno da informação será encapsulada em uma [estrutura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que não foi definida em lugar algum, ela é criada ali na hora do `select`. Qual é o tipo dela? Ninguém sabe. Mas como todo dado em C# precisa ter um tipo, podemos chamá-lo de tipo anônimo. E um tipo anônimo não pode ser declarado explicitamente, portanto a única alternativa é o uso do `var`.

```
var dadosProduto = from p in produtos select new { p.Nome, p.Preco };
```

Nesse exemplo a variável `dadosProduto` terá um tipo `IEnumerable<AlgumTipoGeradoNaHora>`. Esse tipo terá apenas dois campos com nomes (internos) que só o compilador conhece.

Ao contrário do que alguns imaginam, o `var` não é tão obrigatório assim, portanto para os puristas, a escolha deveria ser nunca usá-lo. É possível explicitamente criar antes o tipo necessário para acomodar o resultado do `select` e usar este tipo na consulta. Fica bem longo e ninguém quer fazer isso.

Mas o `var` é isso, apenas uma comodidade, não uma obrigação.

## Polimorfismo

Há um caso em que usar o tipo explicitamente é obrigatório, pelo menos para passar a intenção correta. Se você deseja criar um objeto concreto de um tipo especializado, mas quer que a variável que o contém seja de um tipo mais geral, fica óbvio que declarar o tipo explicitamente se torna necessário:

```
Control botao = new Button();
```

Nesse caso a variável `botao` será do tipo `Control` mas guardará um objeto do tipo `Button` que obviamente é derivada de `Control`.

Ainda dá para evitar se usar um *cast*, mas é uma solução pior e nada recomendada.

## Ambiguidade

Você também não pode usar o `var` quando não inicializa a variável.

```
var produtos; //não funciona
```

Como saber de que tipo é a variável? Não há qualquer informação que indique isso, nem o programador, nem o compilador sabem. Sem saber o tipo exato só é possível declarar uma variável com outra palavra-chave que permita que a verificação seja feita em *runtime* (mas aí é outro assunto e uma forma não equivalente ao que foi perguntado):

```
dynamic variavel;
```

Até seria possível o compilador inferir o tipo pelo seu uso posterior, mas não quiseram complicar o compilador para algo que pode ser discutível. Linguagens funcionais costumam procurar por todo código para descobrir o tipo. Ótimo. Mas se o coitado do programador quiser saber o tipo, terá que fazer o mesmo (claro que IDEs ajudam um pouco). Então parece ser mais sensato ter que deixar explícito no local da declaração se não pode ser determinado ali mesmo.

## Gosto

Fora esses casos há controvérsias quando usar a declaração implícita ou explícita, mesmo entre membros da equipe do C# há divergências.

Alguns dizem que o `var` só deveria ser usado nos casos onde não existe outro jeito ou onde ficaria muito grande fazer um código que o dispensasse, ou seja, só no exemplo citado acima.

## Obviedade

Outros, talvez a maioria, já acham que o `var` deve ser usado em qualquer situação onde o tipo é óbvio e visivelmente identificável. Talvez seja mesmo a forma mais sensata (é a minha :P). Exemplos:

```
var x = 1;
var texto = "exemplo";
var botao = new Button();
var lista = new List<cliente>{ cli1, cli2 };
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Produto, Fornecedor>>();
```

Em todos esses casos o tipo está bem explícito logo ao lado do nome da variável. Não tem necessidade de duplicar esse texto do outro lado. Tá maluco de escrever algo assim, né?

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<Produto, Fornecedor>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Produto, Fornecedor>>();
```

Viu? Não dá nem para ler parte do código que talvez seja mais relevante. E quando você tem quebrar linha demais indica algo errado no código.

## Polêmica

O caso mais polêmico, e que tem apoiadores, é deixar explícito quando o tipo não é óbvio.

```
var valor = CalculaParcelas(total);
```

De que tipo é `valor`? `int`? `float`? `double`? Estranho usar esses tipos, mas poderia ser. `Decimal` parece mais lógico mas poderia ser `bool`, o método poderia jogar o valor em outro lugar e só dizer se deu tudo certo, outra coisa estranha, mas poderia ser. Poderia ser uma `struct` ou `class` qualquer definida pelo programa. Explicitamente fica mais claro com o que você terá que lidar:

```
List<Decimal> valor = CalculaParcelas(total);
```

Faz sentido que você tenha parcelas com valores diferentes por algum critério e que cada valor individual precise ser conhecido, mas não tinha como saber olhando o código.

O Visual Studio pode dar uma dica. E convenhamos que C# não foi feito para se programar sem um IDE (ainda que seja perfeitamente factível sem nenhuma perda exceto um pouco de produtividade, que fará relativamente pouca diferença). Mesmo assim é justo achar que deveria ser visível sem ter que apertar nada ou movimentar o *mouse*.

Mas de qualquer forma se o uso da variável está longe da declaração, você preferirá usar esse recurso do VS em vez de procurar o que está explícito no código.

Com a ferramenta certa ([Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) que claramente incentiva o uso do `var`) seria possível usar o `var` inicialmente para facilitar e com um ou dois cliques ou teclas mudar para o tipo explícito pego da assinatura do método. Isso vai apenas economizar a digitação que não é o melhor motivo do uso do `var`. Já a poluição visual com informação redundante é um bom motivo.

## O `var` pode ser a melhor solução de expressividade

É bem verdade também que em muitos casos o tipo da variável pouco importa. E em alguns casos não saber o tipo pode ser útil. Lembra quando falaram para não usar [notação húngara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)? Eu sei que não é a mesma coisa mas o princípio é o mesmo. Não vincule o tipo à variável explicitando no código. Claro que isso pode trazer *bugs* sutis em alguns casos.

Não é o nome da variável ou método que deve representar sua função no código? Então porque o tipo é tão importante? Sem o tipo escrito no código fica mais fácil dar manutenção em diversas situações.

Então façamos assim:

```
var parcelas = ObterListaParcelas(total);
```

Fica bem mais claro, e sem ser explícito quanto ao tipo, não? Além do nome da variável mostrar que serão parcelas o método diz claramente que vem uma lista de parcelas. Claro que ainda não é certo que é uma `List`, tão pouco de `Decimal`. Mas se a equipe é organizada e seguem padrões até dá para inferir isso com alguma certeza. Não é perfeito mas é quase óbvio.

Evidentemente que a solução final não seria obrigar todos métodos carregarem seu tipo usando notação húngara, assim:

```
var parcelas = PegaParcelasListDecimal(total); //muito feio e possivelmente problemático
```

## Mais polêmica

Mas usando nomes mais representativos nos deixa em um caso ainda mais polêmico:

```
var listaClientes = PegaListaClientes();
```

É semelhante ao que citei na seção anterior. Fica fácil imaginar que o tipo de `lista` será `List<Cliente>`, principalmente se é um software desenvolvido com padrões rígidos de nomenclatura e estilo do que usar. E também dá para identificar fácil qual é o tipo sem auxílio de ferramentas. Claro que o método poderia ter sido desenvolvido por alguém sem noção e retornar um tipo diferente do que o nome indica, ou quem sabe até ter uma razão para isto, mas não é o normal.

Mas sim, precisa imaginar, não é garantido. O temor da dificuldade de identificação faz algum sentido para programadores de linguagens estáticas. Já quem programa em linguagens dinâmicas acha muito normal não ter o tipo e os bons programadores não estão fazendo softwares piores e com menos produtividade por causa disso.

## Escolhendo um critério

É claro que fica mais difícil determinar quando usar ou não nesses casos, a avaliação cairá na subjetividade. Um critério de usar o `var` quando o tipo já está concretamente explícito na declaração é mais objetivo e mais fácil de seguir. Outro critério objetivo é nunca ser explícito, embora radical, possui adeptos.

Quanto mais eu uso o `var` e não tenho dificuldades, mais dá vontade de chegar próximo disto. Por isto a milhagem de cada um pode variar em casos assim. Evidentemente que se você for expor o código para um público externo alguns se irritarão por não ter um tipo declarado explicitamente. Um número provavelmente menor se irritará por ter os tipos poluindo o código. Não dá para agradar a todos. Mas esse é um outro critério para se levar em conta além do gosto.

## Conclusão

Não existem recomendações oficiais. Após tentarem, perceberam que seria um erro fazer essa determinação. O conselho é geral: sempre que for possível escolher qual forma usar, use o que a equipe determinar. Mantenha o padrão mesmo que a equipe seja só você.

Cada vez mais eu vejo que o uso `var` se torna mais prevalente nos código C#. Pelo menos nos casos óbvios. Parece que as pessoas estão aprendendo que é vantajoso e não é acompanhado de problemas.

Curiosamente **as pessoas usam valores sem conhecer o tipo o tempo todo**. Toda vez que ela usa um método ou até mesmo um operador em uma expressão, muitas vezes ela não sabe ao certo qual será o tipo do resultado daquela sub-expressão. Ela não faz um *cast* explícito para o mesmo tipo que dará o resultado, só para deixar explícito. **Por que a declaração implícita deveria causar mais problemas que isto?**

Ninguém se preocupa com o tipo que retorna aqui, simplesmente funciona:

```
ImprimeListaQualquer(PegaListaClientes());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Var.cs).

#### Documentação

Declarar o tipo explicitamente só deveria ser usado quando o programador quer que aquele tipo seja sempre usado. Que uma mudança na inicialização por uma mudança no método que resulta no valor inicial não altere o tipo. Escrever código é documentar algo. Colocando o tipo explicitamente está dizendo que precisa ser daquele tipo, aconteça o que acontecer. Como você documenta que o tipo não é importante? Não colocando-o implicitamente.

Quando vejo código de um programador, um dos muitos critérios para avaliá-lo é o uso de `var`. Quase sempre quem não usa pelo menos nos casos óbvios, ou a pessoa desconhece o recurso ou tem apego à regras inúteis, o que diz muito sobre sua qualificação. Claro que não pode ser o único critério e deve-se levar em conta o contexto, por exemplo se não é código legado, afinal o `var` existe "só" desde 2007, ou se ele faz por "imposição" da equipe.

Referências (opiniões):

- No SO [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16881801/221800) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/221800).
- No [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125262/389).
- No [InfoQ](https://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/CSharp-var).
- No [blog de quem implementou o recurso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na linguagem. Talvez o mais próximo de uma "recomendação oficial".
- [Blog que indica haver diferenças entre documentos oficiais](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124022255/http://gregbee.ch/blog/to-var-or-not-to-var-implicit-typing-is-the-question).
- [Autoridade em C++ sobre o `auto`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180616/389) (equivalente do `var`).

## Extra

C# 9 tem uma [nova feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100) que pode fazer o `var` ser bem menos usado.

Comment: Sou daqueles que só utiliza o `var` quando a determinação do tipo é óbvia. Concordo consigo em que o importante é definir um padrão e segui-lo sempre. Dito isto, acho que é redutor avaliar um programador em função de como, ou se, ele utiliza o `var`.

Comment: Só gostaria de fazer duas observações, tipos explícitos são melhores em grandes equipes de desenvolvimento, onde os padrões e clareza de código tem que ser mais rígidos. O outro aspecto importante é a segurança, se você usar algum trecho com componentes de terceiros e nao conhecer a implementação ou se usa código não gerenciado.

Comment: A primeira afirmação é o que eu falei, é gosto, da equipe, mas ainda é gosto. Sobre a segurança não parece fazer sentido. @ramaral eu escrevi um parágrafo que mostra que este critério não é fundamental, é um componente. Se a avaliação for importante para alguma coisa, certamente ele será questionado sobre isto e pode até usar a defesa para mostrar o oposto, que ele tomou a decisão com critério.

Comment: Se você usa tipos implicitamente e passa para outra rotina fazer o cast, se ela não usa código gerenciado, pode provocar overflow.

Comment: @Intruso Cite um exemplo, mostre uma fonte disto. Se o código depois de compilado é exatamente o mesmo não tem porque acontecer o que você está dizendo. Código não gerenciado podem causar problema não importa como ele foi declarado no gerenciado, até porque esta diferença de declaração só afeta o que humanos leem.

Comment: @bigown, código compilado não é código seguro. Quando falei de código não gerenciado, tentei puxar um caso mais claro porque você pode facilmente passar um ponteiro para um valor recebido de um escopo acima e esperar um tipo menor numa instrução e depois Kabum!!!!! Mas, você quer um cenário mais simples e com código gerenciado, tente usar var i = 0 e realizar algumas multiplicações com ele, mesmo para quantidades de registros/valores mais comuns em sistemas comerciais e você vai ter facilmente um overflow. Um grande varejo hoje passa facilmente o valor maximo de um int32 em produtos vendidos.

Answer (score 20):

Creio que seja muito mais uma questão de legíbilidade do que qualquer outra coisa. Quando li sobre isso encontrei discussões sobre o tema, e as recomendações vão depender do que a pessoa acha desse tópico.

Eu creio que usar var torna o código mais legível. Se tenho uma classe Pedido que possui Produtos e quero colocar isso numa variável, faria assim:

```
var pedidos = cliente.Pedidos;
```

Eu não ligo se pedidos é uma List, uma ImmutableList ou IEnumerable, provavelmente eu só quero iterar por ela. Mas se fizermos assim:

```
ImmutableList<Pedido> pedidos = cliente.Pedidos;
```

Pra mim, estamos adicionando informação desnecessária. Há quem argumente que o var não facilita na legibilidade quando atribuimos um valor retornado de um método à variável. Algo como:

```
var pedidos = ObterPedidos();
```

Mas para mim ainda não faz diferença - ainda sei que estou lidando com pedidos. Quem usa esse argumento geralmente dá um nome de método estúpido (como `CalcularValores`) e diz que não tem a informação que precisa ao usar var nessa situação - mas pra mim, aí o problema é outro ;)

Por fim, var traz outra grande vantagem, se você quiser mudar o tipo de retorno do método e não usar var, vai ter que mudar a declaração em todos os lugares onde ele é chamado, o que não é necessário se fazer ao empregar var.

Comment: Considero este um ponto muito importante. Se existe necessidade de explicitar o tipo para deixar o código mais claro, é um sinal de que os nomes (e eventualmente muito mais coisa no design) estão ainda com um enorme potencial para serem melhoradas. +1

Comment: @Caffé gostei do "um enorme potencial para serem melhoradas".

Answer (score 12):

Nos primórdios, a documentação da **Microsoft** incluía uma nota dizendo que o uso excessivo de **var** quando não necessário podia prejudicar a legibilidade do código. Depois a pópria Microsoft retirou este parágrafo.

As respostas curtas para suas perguntas são:

> nos casos em que ele é opcional, a escolha é puramente uma questão de
> estilo?

**Sim**, é puramente uma questão de estilo uma vez que tecnicamente não há ganhos ou perdas - o tipo da variável será definido em tempo de compilação tanto quanto se ele tivesse sido explicitamente declarado.

> Existem recomendações (oficiais ou não, contanto que justificadas)
> para se utilizar ou evitar o var em determinadas situações?

**Existem recomendações não oficiais, entretanto justificadas apenas por opiniões**, sempre discutíveis, o que nos leva à resposta da primeira pergunta: é uma questão de estilo.

> Quando usar var em C#?

Você é obrigado a usar o **var** como no caso que você mencionou e não pode usá-lo em alguns outros casos, listados na [documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061(v=vs.90).aspx).

Nos demais casos, é uma questão de estilo.

#### Comentário:

**C#**, embora estaticamente tipado por natureza, já nasceu menos verborrágico que o **Java**, por exemplo, e já permite tipagem dinâmica e já tem vários elementos das linguagens funcionais. A palavra chave **var** foi um grande acerto, permite um código ainda mais limpo e nos leva na direção de um código mais expressivo também - podemos trocar o artifício de explicitar o tipo da variável pela prática de dar nomes significativos aos nossos artefatos.

Assim, apesar de que isto será sempre uma questão de estilo, o estilo que vai predominar como recomendado será o de usar **var** sempre que permitido pela linguagem - **processo para tomada de decisão: "se o compilador permite, então usa"**.

Comment: O que é uma linguagem "verborrágica" ou "verbosa"?

Comment: @drmcarvalho É uma linguagem que oferece menos atalhos, exigindo mais texto para codificar um recurso. Exemplo: em Java, propriedades read/write são implementadas declarando-se um campo interno e codificando-se explicitamente dois métodos (um getter e um setter), enquanto em C# você faz o mesmo escrevendo uma única linha. Verborragia é uma qualidade subjetiva, e geralmente é atribuída por comparação - "a linguagem B é mais verborrágica que a linguagem A". Além disso, atalhos que não existem hoje na linguagem podem surgir amanhã.