# Como -1 pode ser maior que 4?

Tags: c, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Como este código pode [executar desta forma](http://ideone.com/EAkQmM)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("tamanho de um inteiro: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    if(sizeof(int) > -1) {
        printf("4 é maior que -1");
    } else {
        printf("-1 é maior que 4");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
-1 é maior que 4
```

Intuitivamente -1 deve ser menor que 4 sempre, porque acontece este tipo de "erro"? O computador não é uma máquina que não erra?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Mesmo que minha mãe e alguns programadores achem que o computador toma suas próprias decisões, ele só é capaz de fazer o que humanos determinam.

Claro que um computador pode produzir resultados errados sem um humano errar usando ele. Mas isso significa que um humano projetou o computador ou pelo menos algum componente dele de forma errada. Ou a especificação determinou que o erro será possível, e quem for utilizar aquele hardware precisa estar ciente disto e tomar as devidas providências para isso não trazer resultados indesejados. Na prática os erros ocorrem mais nos softwares mesmo.

Os programadores cometem muitos erros, frequentemente porque não entendem todos os aspectos do que ele estão fazendo. É normal. Não existe ninguém que sabe tudo de tudo, mesmo que esse tudo seja só sobre desenvolvimento de software.

Esse "problema" específico ocorre por causa da diferença de tipos utilizado do código. Não é muito óbvio mas se procurar na especificação verá que o operador [`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) retorna um valor de tipo `unsigned int`, mais especificamente um [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) e a comparação no `if` está sendo feito com um `signed int` ou simplesmente `int`. Ou seja, está comparando um tipo que tem sinal com outro que não tem. Por isso há uma conversão implícita do tipo sinalizado para o tipo não sinalizado. Nesta conversão há uma mudança na interpretação do dado.

Sabendo que o retorno do operador usado é um inteiro sem sinal e que o *cast* implícito ocorre e ainda que um valor negativo quando convertido para um tipo sem sinal começa a contagem do maior inteiro possível e vai reduzindo quanto mais for o negativo - já que ele ignora o *bit* de sinal como um sinal e o considera como parte do número - fica fácil entender o que está ocorrendo. E o problema é só uma interpretação errada de um humano. O computador fez o que mandaram ele fazer.

Fica mais fácil entender imprimindo o -1 sem sinal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("tamanho de um inteiro: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("-1 com cast: %u\n", -1);
    if(sizeof(int) > -1) {
        printf("4 é maior que -1");
    } else {
        printf("-1 é maior que 4");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Então a mensagem deveria ser "4294967295 é maior que 4".

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9Mg4T9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/UnsignedProblem2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/UnsignedProblem2.c).

Algumas pessoas vão aproveitar isso para criticar a conversão implícita. De fato ela é ruim quando espera-se que a linguagem será usada por programadores que não entendem bem todo funcionamento do que ele está usando ou de quem costuma ter desatenções. Mas acho que mais ajuda que atrapalha.

De uma certa forma isso remete ao que eu [respondi em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47386/101). O fato de você não saber o tipo que uma expressão resulta é o real problema do código. Deixar tudo explícito ajudaria a evitar alguns problemas mas deixaria o código mais longo e redundante adicionando um detalhe desnecessário. Ironicamente isso pode ser benéfico em linguagens que tem como alvo programadores que não se preocupam com os detalhes.

## Conclusão

Saiba os tipos de toda sub-expressão que está computando. E garanta que está usando os tipos certos. Neste caso se a intenção realmente é comparar o tamanho do tipo com literal inteiro sinalizado, então deve garantir que o resultado de `sizeof(int)` seja um `int` através de um *cast*. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("tamanho de um inteiro: %d\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    if((int)sizeof(int) > -1) printf("4 é maior que -1");
    else printf("-1 é maior que 4");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/th39Rv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/UnsignedProblem). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/UnsignedProblem.c).

Este par de pergunta e resposta foi inspirado em uma [discussão no Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2t1p1q/how_1_is_greater_than_4/) que achei interessante mostrar.

Comment: Realmente interessante. 
Obrigado por compartilhar!

Answer (score 35):

Na verdade `sizeof` retorna um tipo size_t, devendo ser do tipo unsigned. O problema ocorre na conversão binário signed para binário unsigned, caso o programador não tenha cuidado.
A conversão de um número binário para um inteiro decimal negativo como -1, por exemplo, é feito em C pelo complemento de dois do seu equivalente positivo.

Exemplo de como o computador enxerga um número negativo:
Pega o número 1 -- positivo -- em forma binária com o tamanho de 4 bytes (32 bits, ou 32 dígitos binários):

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 -> binário de 1
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 -> complemento de um (inverte-se os bits)
                                + 1 -> complemento de dois (soma 1 ao complemento)
___________________________________
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 -> complemento de dois equivalendo a -1
```

O problema ocorre quando o computador trata um número que deveria ser negativo como positivo. Por exemplo, o número decimal -1 acima, tratado como positivo é reconhecido pelo computador como 4294967295 decimal, que obviamente é maior que o número 4 do seu mesmo tipo.

Levando em conta isso, deve-se ter bastante cuidado de como o computador e a linguagem de programação lida com a conversão implícita de tipos. Estude bastante casting para ter certeza de sempre fazê-la de maneira segura.