# Qual finalidade do unsigned no C++?

Tags: c, c++, tipagem

Qual a finalidade do `unsigned` no C++?

Exemplo:  `unsigned char ch2;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assim como no C, o `unsigned` sozinho serve para nada (exceto o mostrado abaixo), ele é um modificador para determinar que um tipo numérico inteiro é sem sinal. Ou seja, você só terá valores positivos nele. Ele determina se o bit mais significativo será considerado o sinal de positivo ou negativo ou se este bit entrará no valor, por isso ele permite o dobro dos valores permitidos.

Um `int` vai de -2147483648 à 2147483647.

Um `unsigned int` vai de 0 à 4294967295.

O mesmo vale para o `char` ou `short` ou `long`.

Note que o `char` com a intenção de representar um caractere não usa o modificador. Apenas quando ele é usado para representar um número de 8 bits que é interessante usar o modificador para tornar explícito.

Se usar apenas `unsigned` sem especificar mais nada, o `int` é assumido.

Em geral há a recomendação de usar este tipo de dado só se realmente for necessário e se o programador entender todas as suas implicações ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101)). Não use porque você não quer valores negativos, ele não dá garantias.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os exemplos dados estão corretos caso o `int` ocupe 32 bits, mas é bom notar que isso pode não ser o caso.

Comment: É verdade. Peguei o caso comum.

Answer (score 9):

As variáveis numéricas podem ser sinalizadas ou não. Sinalizadas significa que o primeiro bit (o da esquerda) indica o sinal: 0: o número é positivo, 1, o número é negativo.

Como em muitas aplicações não faz sentido ter um número negativo (exemplo número de peças, quantidade de filhos, idade, etc.), é possível usar variáveis sem esse sinal:

> Uma variável de 8 bits com sinal vai de -128 a 127
>   A mesma variável, se for unsigned, vai de 0 a 255.

### Mas qual o sentido para `char`?

Se a variável char é usada para registrar um caractere, use `char` simplesmente. Mas encontramos o mesmo tipo usado para registrar valores numéricos. Neste caso use `signed char` ou `unsigned char`.

Baseado em [What is an unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75191/1387277).

Answer (score 7):

Tipos de dados marcados como `unsigned` significa que só aceitarão valores positivos (incluindo o `0`).

Vários tipos de dados podem ser marcados como `signed` ou `unsigned`:

```
Tipo de dados       Tipo de assinatura padrão
-------------------------------------------------
short            -> signed short
signed short
unsigned short
int              -> signed int
signed int
unsigned int
signed           -> signed int
unsigned         -> unsigned int
long             -> signed long
signed long
unsigned long
char                (is signed or unsigned depending on the implmentation)
signed char
unsigned char
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099874/3497987)</sub>

O tipo `char` também pode ser assinado, mas deve-se tomar cuidado.

Se você está usando `char` como texto, use então sem marca-lo:

- Quando for carácter literal como 'a' ou '0'.
- Quando o valor for usado para formar *strings* como "abcde"
- Também funciona como valor numérico, mas que não foi especificado para ser tratado como `signed` ou `unsigned`. Cuidado com comparação de desigualdade se não estiver limitando ao ASCII (0-127).

Se você está usando carácter do tipo numérico, use:

- `signed char`, quando os valores forem de -127 à 127. (-128 à 127 é comum)
- `unsigned char`, quando for valores positivos de 0 à 255.

"Pelo menos", porque o padrão C++ só dá o intervalo mínimo de valores que cada tipo numérico precisa. `sizeof (char)` precisa ser 1 (um byte), mas um *byte* em teoria pode ser por exemplo 32 *bits*, `sizeof` ainda teria o seu tamanho como 1, o que significa que você poderia ter `sizeof (char) == sizeof (long) == 1`.

<sub>[Fonte²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87648/3497987)</sub>