# Em quais ocasiões devo utilizar um unsigned char ou um char em C?

Tags: c, char

Recentemente andei lendo um pouco sobre a diferença entre um `char` e um `unsigned char`. Consegui entender a diferença básica entre os dois, entretanto, não captei a ideia por traz do uso de um `unsigned char`, ou melhor, eu praticamente não sei quando é a hora certa de se usar um `char` ou um `unsigned char`.

Portanto, venho aqui com a seguinte questão: Em quais ocasiões devo utilizar um `unsigned char` ou um `char` em C?

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77418/101

Comment: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/C-C++/Em-quais-ocasioes-devo-utilizar-um-unsigned-char-ou-um-char-em-C

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente não só no char como em int, float entre outros, temos os tipos signed e o unsigned (há outros além desses), a diferença é que o bit mais significativo que faz a alteração de valores positivos para negativos é ignorado e utilizado como espaço, sendo assim é liberado mas espaço, já em contrapartida os números negativos não são possíveis. Veja a tabela a seguir, todos os unsigneds começam com 0

**obs:**  Vale ressaltar que por padrão é utilizado o signed
portanto você declarar

```
signed char = 2;
```

e declarar

```
char = 2;
```

daria no mesmo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim respondendo a pergunta você declarar um um char o maximo que pode ser inserido nele seria 127

```
char valor = 127;
```

já colocando ele para insigned ele vai até o 255 então seria possivel fazer

```
unsigned char valor = 255;
```

porém não seria possivel adicionar negativo no unsigned.

Porque isso acontece? vamos pegar o char como exemplo, o char contém 8 bits, sendo assim os possiveis valores (1 ou 0) temos 2 opções dentre 8 bits, elevando isso ficaria 2^8 = 256 sendo assim temos de 0 a 255 de espaço, porém dentre esses 8 bits, 1 é utilizado para mudar, determinar se é negativo ou positivo sendo possivel o uso de 7, sendo assim 2 ^ 7 = 128 se contar de 0 ficaria 0 - 127.

Portanto char ainda utiliza o bit para positivo e negativo fazendo com que fique com 127 de tamanho maximo, logo se você usar o unsigned e ignorar isso seria possivel utilizar os 8 bits  ignorando o controle de positivo e negativo, ficando 2^8 = 256, portanto contando de 0 ficariamos com 255 de tamanho maximo no char.