# Por que o valor sempre retorna 0?

Tags: c, tipagem, memória, declaração-de-variável

No código abaixo o resultado da variável `valor_1` sempre é 0.

Porém invertendo a ordem da declaração das variáveis para `unsigned char valor_2, valor_1;` o programa funciona corretamente.

Qual é o problema aqui?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    unsigned char valor_1, valor_2;

    printf("\nDigite um numero para o valor 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor_1);

    printf("Digite um numero para o valor 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor_2);

    printf("\nvalor 1: %d", valor_1);
    printf("\nvalor 2: %d\n", valor_2);
}
```

Comment: Giusepe, você quer trabalhar com números ou caracteres? Você declarou as variáveis como char, mas está utilizando o %d que é para inteiros.

Comment: A ideia é trabalhar com números entre 0 e 255.

Answer (score 6):

Não existe o que está pensando fazer. O tipo `char` ou mesmo `unsigned char` possuem 1 byte e portanto só podem representar 256 valores diferentes, mas nada impede de usar valores diferentes disto, e do jeito que está fazendo se for colocado números diferentes aceitará e possivelmente corromperá a memória (ele ocupará mais bytes do que você reservou). Em C é assim, você tem que cuidar da memória.

No caso o `char`

Se deseja que só aceite estes valores terá que validar isso, não ache que o tipo fará alguma coisa por você, ele só serve para reservar espaço na memória e se tentar colocar um valor que não cabe no espaço da memória será um problema que pode até passar desapercebido.

A não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte, e neste caso não tem, use o simples e óbvio, prefira um tipo `int` mesmo que ele ocupe mais espaço na memória não causará problema, pelo contrário, ajuda dar menos problema (mas pode ainda). E [nunca use `unsigned` sem ter um completo domínio da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77418/101) e todas consequências disto.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int valor_1, valor_2;
    printf("\nDigite um numero para o valor 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor_1);
    printf("Digite um numero para o valor 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor_2);
    printf("\nvalor 1: %d", valor_1);
    printf("\nvalor 2: %d\n", valor_2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Int256c). E [no **repl.it**](https://ideone.com/jDU0vi). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Int256.c).

Answer (score 2):

Em C, o programa no momento de execução não "sabe" nada sobre tamanho de variáveis - com alguma sorte o compilador nao deixa seu programa compilar. O `printf` e `scanf` apesar de muito usados, são construções bem coplexas em cima do C para facilitar a entrada e saída de tipos de dados um pouco mais complexos - mas para usar ambos é melhor (1) seguir exatamente a receita que você viu, ou (2) ler alguma documentação completa, e saber exatamente o que está acontecendo.

No caso, dentre os códigos de tipos de dados do printf e do scanf, NÂO EXISTE uma marcação para um tipo numérico com tamanho de 1 byte. O tipo "%c" sim, é entendido como um tipo de 1 byte, mas a função trabalha com o número como texto (isso é, ele é enviado (ou lido) como 1 byte para o terminal, não a sua representação decimal de 0 a 255 (ou -128 a 127)).

Quando se usa o tipo %d para imprimir uma variável char como número no printf, isso funciona por quê:

1. O compilador sabe, por conta da definição do printf, que pode por qualquer tipo de dados como argumento para o printf que ele "se vira".
2. No entanto, a arquitetura das CPUs de PCs modernos não suporta colocar valores com tamanho menor que 4 bytes - iguais ao de um inteiro nativo - na pilha, para serem passados como parâmetros - então o compilador converte seu número na variável "char" para um "int 32" (ou 64, depende da arquitura e dos flags para o compilador), na passagem de argumentos
3. Se fosse uma função com parâmetros bem definidos que fosse aceitar um argumento do tipo "char" ou "unsigned char" do lado que está sendo chamado, o código gerado para essa função iria pegar só os 8 bits menos significativos da pilha, e descartar os 3 bytes restantes, e todos ficariam felizes.
4. No caso do printf, não é predefinido o que ele vai pegar da pilha - o código programado dele é que ele olha a string de formatação, e assume que aqueles dados, na ordem em que aparecem, estão na pilha passados como argumentos. Ele ve um "%d", e pega um inteiro ( 4 ou 8 bytes) - como o compilador gerou código para "estivar" o "char" na hora de coloca-lo na pilha, isso funciona bem. Se o printf encontra um "%c", pega o byte menos significativo da pilha, e insere ele "como veio ao mundo" na stream que vai imprimir. (No caso do %d, o printf converte o número para a representação decimal em texto de seu valor, antes de coloca-lo na string - isso é, tem uma chamada a "itoa" ou equivalente lá dentro).
5. No caso do scanf - a coisa muda: O scanf vê um %d, **e entende que tem um espaço de 4 (ou 8) bytes na memória para armazenar o valor, no local indicado pelo ponteiro passado**. Ele lê um número em texto, faz sua chamada interna ao `atoi` ou equivalente, pega o valor de retorno - um inteiro nativo, e escreve todos os bytes na posição de memória

Nno seu caso, na posição de `valor_1`. Como na maior parte das arquiteturas, os números são gravados de forma "little endian" - isso é, o byte menos significativo vai na posição de memória mais baixa, se você digita "255" para o SCANF, ele vai gerar o inteiro de 32 bits que podemos represnetar por  "0x000000ff", e esse "ff" vai na posição exata do ponteiro passsado - o "valor_1", por isso o número aparece lá. Só que os outros 3 bytes com zero, vão ser armazenados nas posições de memória seguintes - o proximo na posiçao de `valor_2` (dependendo das configurações do compilador), e os outros 2 por cima de outras variáveis, ou outros dados internos usados pelo programa.  Isso é o que gera o comportamento que você está vendo, e que só por um acaso de sorte não gera uma falha de segmentação.

Nos sistemas operacionais modernos, uma falha de segmentação nesse ponto é só um erro a mais impresso no terminal, e a vida segue.  Mas, por exemplo, do windows 3 até o XP, a sua chance de que esse singelo programinha desse uma tela azul e obrigasse a renicialização do computador era BEM grande. E numa máquina com microcontrolador, como arduíno, esse mesmo erro pode gerar um comportamento indefinido, resultando inclusive em queima de componentes.

A linguagem C é uma das ferramentas mais poderosas para programar computadores, e permite o uso bruto da CPU pra fazer o que você quiser - no entanto convem saber o que se está fazendo. O uso de C como primeira linguagem de programação em muitos programas de curso de faculdade e técnicos, sem dar primeiro enfase na arquitetura e como esses dados trafegam, e deixar os alunos criarem programas com "printf" e "scanf" e apagar a tela com "system(cls)"  no entanto **é um erro** (*) - hoje em dia linguagens de mais alto nível permitem uma criação de uma interface de entrada de dados numéricos e textuais de forma muito mais simples, em que o aprendiz pode se preocupar com a lógica, e não tentar adivinhar o que está acontecendo por dentro, em funções que foram criadas como atalhos mas que tem brechas perigosíssimas, quando os computadores não tinha memória suficiente para algo mais sofisticadoo. (isso são o printf, o scanf, e mesmo o gets e puts). Se você usar Python, Java, Javascript vai poder fazer quantos exercícios quiser com entrada e saída de dados no terminal até aprender bem "if" "else", funções, contas básicas, etc...sem o perigo de explodir o computador ("explodir" é figurado em ambientes seguros como Linux, OsX ou WIndows mais recentes,  mas pode não ser num Arduíno)

**TL;DR**: É legal tentar brincar com os tamanhos de dados e ensina bastante coisa, mas isso não vai funcionar com `scanf`  -sempre passe um `int` para o scanf - você pode ter variaveis `unsigned char` e passar o valor que veio do scanf para elas com `=` depois do retorno, e usa-las com `printf` sem ter muitos problemas. Se o seu objetivo no entanto é só a lógica de "if", funções, e contas, deixe  o C para as "lições de casa",e brinque com javascript, Python, PHP - vai conseguir fazer experiências e aprender mais rápido do que se tiver que literalmente se preocupar com onde vai cada byte na memória, o que acontece com programas em C.

(*) Estou a disposição dos seus professores e coordenadores de curso para conversar sobre isso se quiser.