# Intervalo das variáveis em C

Tags: c, variáveis, tipagem, char

Nunca consegui compreender a questão do intervalo das variáveis, sei que cada uma ocupa um determinado espaço na memória, mas e o intervalo o que significa? Quando digo que uma variável `char` assume valores em um intervalo entre -128 a 127, este valor significa o que? Nas variáveis numéricas até faz sentido, seria o intervalo numérico que a variável pode assumir, mas e as variáveis do tipo `char`?

Comment: Menor valor e maior valor passíveis de serem representados com tal tipo de variável, no caso um byte considerando sinal.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrário do que o nome diz, e da crença popular, o tipo `char` não é um tipo de texto, ele é um tipo numérico de um byte que permite 256 valores diferentes. Por acaso ela é usada para expressar símbolos gráficos de texto, mas isso nem é obrigatório e de fato nem é possível armazenar algo assim.

## Abstração

Na verdade todo tipo é só numérico se baixar um pouco a abstração adotada, e é sempre montado através de sinais 0 e 1 que as pessoas conhecem como binário.

Mas o tipo `char` nem precisa baixar a abstração para entender que ele é numérico, ele é isso mesmo. Se você mandar imprimir o valor de um tipo `char` sem dizer que quer um texto o que será impresso é um número (na verdade é quase isso, veja mais detalhe abaixo).

## Faixa de valor e tamanho

A faixa de valor real do tipo precisa ser consultada na hora de usar de acordo com o `CHAR_MIN` e `CHAR_MAX` disponíveis no arquivo `limits.h`. Não há garantias em especificação da linguagem que seja o valor informado na pergunta, pode ser de 0 à 255 também. Poderia ser até outras coisas, mas é bem raro ou inexistente.

O que a especificação diz é que esse tipo deve possuir **um byte**. Algumas pessoas usam `sizeof char` para descobrir o tamanho onde precisa dessa informação, mas não faz sentido, é garantido ter esse tamanho, é diferente de outros tipos que realmente o tamanho pode variar. É possível não ter 8 bits, mas isso é bem raro. Aí teria que consultar o `CHAR_BIT` disponível pelo compilador no mesmo arquivo dito acima.

Se quer saber porque pode representar sempre 256 valores diferente é porque o byte tem 8 bits (e por ser bits só pode ter dois valores, o 0 ou o 1), então 2 elevado à 8 dá 256, assim como em decimal temos 10 dígitos possível e se você tiver capacidade para 4 dígitos o máximo que pode chegar é 10 elevado à 4, portanto 10.000.

## Caractere

Então podemos considerar que esse tipo é um byte. Por acaso em grande parte das situações o usamos como se fosse um caractere.

Esse caractere é obtido através de uma tabela chamada [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Lá diz qual caractere deve ser considerado para cada valor numérico encontrado em algum valor desse tipo. É um mapa de representação do texto a ser usado.

Ali tem códigos de controle, todas as letras do alfabeto minúsculas e maiúsculas, algarismo, símbolos matemáticos e para outras funções. A tabela original pode ir de 0 à 127, mas alguns casos usam de 128 à 255 também. Veja qual é o número de cada caractere no *link* acima.

Quando você manda explicitamente ou implicitamente em alguma função imprimir o caractere e não o número que é usado no valor então o **caractere** sairá no hardware usado para a impressão, internamente no computador é só **número**.

Então o que está vendo ali é uma representação textual de um código numérico.

Vamos dizer que mandou imprimir o caractere 0. O código numérico disso era 48. Sim, o código do caractere '0' não é 0. Portanto o dado do tipo `char` é o número 48.

Se mandar imprimir um código numérico 0 nada será impresso, porque ele é usado para indicar nada, novamente, vide a tabela.

Por isso quando manda imprimir um número na verdade ele não será impresso como está no computador, haverá uma conversão do número para uma sequência de caractere(s) e é essa sequência de caractere(s) que será impressa. Porque é assim que o ser humano entende. O número mesmo é montado de um jeito no computador que o humano não entende, ele é só uma sequência de zeros e uns "sem sentido". E note que não estou dizendo que zeros e uns seriam impressos, é mais confuso ainda, porque você só pode imprimir texto então sempre haverá uma conversão para caracteres antes de imprimir, mas sem um algoritmo adequado a conversão será feita para caracteres que não fazem sentido para você.

Por exemplo, um inteiro seria convertido, na maioria das vezes já que depende do tamanho na plataforma, em 4 caracteres.

Sabe aqueles exercícios de converter binário para decimal? É mais ou menos isso que ele faz internamente, só que do jeito certo e eficiente. Esses exercícios passam a impressão que você está convertendo número, mas está convertendo número para a representação textual, números são números, eles não podem ser convertidos entre si porque é a mesma coisa. O texto serve para humanos, o texto é usado porque nós entendemos assim. O número 123 vale 123 unidades não importa se está vendo de forma decimal, hexadecimal ou binário que é só a forma que você lê.

Quando você olha em um papel escrito um número você sempre pensa nele como número, mas na verdade ali só tem um texto com algarismos. Você usa outra abstração para entender melhor o que é aquilo, mas concretamente é só um texto. Comece pensar diferente sobre isso.

## Conclusão

Então se entende a faixa de valores de outros tipos inteiros como `short`, `int` ou `long`, entende o `char` também, só não achava que ele era um tipo numérico inteiro.

Há quem prefira ser mais explícito e usar o tipo completo `signed char` ou `unsigned char`. Isso [pode ser mais confuso em certos cenários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77418/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Esse valor, 128, é referente a tabela ASCII(American Standard Code  for  Information  Interchange), como descrito neste artigo de [iniciação científica da UNICAMP](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~wainer/cursos/2s2011/Cap03-TiposBasicos-texto.pdf):

> Quando  uma 
>   variável  é  declarada  como  do  tipo char o programador já indica
>   sua intenção de utilizar a variável para armazenar símbolos.  A
>   correspondência entre símbolos e números é dada pela tabela ASCII
>   (American Standard Code  for  Information  Interchange). Esta  tabela
>   utiliza os  números  de 0 até 127 para letras do alfabeto inglês e
>   para os sinais de pontuação mais comuns. Por exemplo, na entrada 65 da
>   tabela ASCII encontramos a letra 'A'. Assim, uma variável do tipo char
>   cujo conteúdo seja  65  representaria  também  a  letra  'A'.
>   Infelizmente  não  existe  consenso  de  como  tratar os  caracteres 
>   numerados  a  partir  de  128,  onde  estariam  os  caracteres 
>   acentuados,  e  isso  é causa  de  incompatibilidades  entre 
>   programas  que  compilam  e  executam  em  plataformas diferentes.

Recomendo ler também: [Tipos de dados em C](http://linguagemc.com.br/tipos-de-dados-em-c/) e [Tabela Ascii](https://www.ime.usp.br/~kellyrb/mac2166_2015/tabela_ascii.html).

Comment: A resposta foi editada, caso queira fazer mais alguma sugestão!

Comment: :-)  ficou legal agora  -vou apagar os comentários anteriores.

Comment: Caso queira sugerir algum link ou artigo interessante para ser anexado à resposta, serei grato! Obrigado pelos comentários.