# Utilização de modificadores de tipos de dado

Tags: c++, tipagem

Curiosamente, queria muito saber o porquê dos os modificadores de tipos de dados não serem tão utilizados. É dito que os modificadores são utilizados para "eficiencializar" o desempenho do programa, uma vez que você especifica pro computador exatamente o tipo de informação que será acoplada naquela variável, entretanto, não os vejo sendo utilizados quando poderiam em diversas aplicações.

Teria algum motivo especifico pra isso?

Se eu fosse criar uma variável ajudante de *loop*, que não portaria nenhum dado importante, mas sim ajudando implicitamente no programa, por que não utilizar os modificadores?

Exemplo:

```
unsigned short int ajudanteVariavel = 0;

    while (ajudanteVariavel < 3)
    {
        switch(ajudanteVariavel)
        {
            case 0:
                cout << "First print";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Second print";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Third print";
                break;
        }

        ajudanteVariavel++;
    }
```

Enquanto na realidade, o operador int é utilizado em quase todos os momentos:

```
int ajudanteVariavel = 0;

    while (ajudanteVariavel < 3)
    {
        switch(ajudanteVariavel)
        {
            case 0:
                cout << "First print";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Second print";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Third print";
                break;
        }

        ajudanteVariavel++;
    }
```

Teria algum motivo especifico pra eles não serem tão utilizados? Ou é o meu conceito de aplicação que está equivocado?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Qual o ganho que espera com isso? Se acha que terá algum ganho precisa justificá-lo.

Normalmente isso é usado quando realmente precisa de algo sem sinal, que seja fundamental que ele seja assim, que precisa dos 4 bilhões que ele pode chegar. Outro uso, questionável, é quando claramente os números usados **não podem** ter negativos.

[Nem todo mundo entende tudo que tem que tomar cuidado para usar tipos não sinalizados](http://c-faq.com/expr/preservingrules.html) (tanto que *warnings são gerados em alguns casos, mas não em todos). Para que usar algo diferente?

Usar um tipo não sinalizado sozinho não é um grande problema ([mas é também](http://www.soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned)). O problema começa ocorrer quando mistura os sinalizados com os não sinalizados. E as bibliotecas exigem mais o uso do tipo sinalizado, então vai misturar em algum momento. Antes de começar misturar tem que saber bem como fazer as conversões, tem que ter certeza que ficará sempre atento para evitar [problemas do tipo mostrado nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101). Não faltam [exemplos de problemas](https://critical.eschertech.com/2010/04/07/danger-unsigned-types-used-here/).

## Otimização

Os processadores são otimizados para trabalhar com `int`. A semântica mais óbvia com números é o que o `int` oferece.

Na verdade se for pensar bem faria até mais sentido usar um `char` no exemplo mostrado (vai até 255 que é suficiente e ocupa só 1 byte). Pra que precisa de um tipo que chega a 2 bilhões se precisa de apenas 3 ou pouco mais que isso? Certamente são poucos porque está usando em `switch`. Por outro lado cabe a pergunta novamente, qual o ganho?

Em algumas arquiteturas um `char` pode ser mais lento que um `int`.

Tem quem ache que vai ter ganho de memória em usar um `char` no lugar de um `int`, mas é comum que seja feito um *padding* automático para alinhar memória e o consumo acaba sendo o mesmo.

Em alguns casos pode haver certas otimizações quando o tipo não é sinalizado. Se precisa disto tem que entender quando ocorre e saber quando seu uso pode ser útil e não vai causar outros problemas.

## Há muito uso de tipos não sinalizados

Operações de bits (máscaras, tamanhos e alguns contadores, combinação de dados, representações específicas segmentadas como data/tempo, etc.) costumam funcionar melhor com tipos não sinalizados. Mas a maioria dos problemas não precisa lidar com isso.

Na verdade programadores experientes muitas vezes preferem um `int32_t` em muita situações já que eles possuem tamanho fixo em todas plataformas e dá mais controle ao que está fazendo. Mas pode ter alguma perda mínima de performance. O `int` é para ser o tipo mais performático da plataforma com um tamanho mínimo garantido (16 bits), mas pode ser maior e nas plataformas modernas costuma ser (geralmente 32 bits). Mas alguns guias de estilo "proíbem" o uso desses tipos. Deve ter alguma razão.

Em outros casos preferem `size_t` que é um tipo não sinalizado. Note que esse tipo é muito usado em casos reais. Se você olhar a maioria das respostas aqui sobre C ou C++ usa-se `int` porque funciona, mas em casos reais o tipo não sinalizado (com modificador como a pergunta o chama) é até usado sim, quando faz sentido. Onde vê:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {  
    //algo aqui
}
```

em códigos profissionais, quando faz sentido costuma ser escrito assim:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    //algo aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/Size.cpp).

Quando você vê códigos de iniciantes ou leigos, pode desconfiar. Mas se vê programadores experientes fazendo algo de um jeito eles sabem que aquilo é o melhor. Não estou dizendo que não deva questionar, pelo contrário, precisa entender porque.

O que eu vejo muito é programador ingênuo não entender todas nuances dos tipos e usar o mais fácil e óbvio sem pensar em todas implicações. É o que ocorre na maioria dos exemplos simples, nos exercícios. Produzir código C/C++ real normalmente obriga pensar um pouco mais sobre tipos.

## Conclusão

Eu acredito (campo opinativo) que muitas pessoas, especialmente em exercícios, usam sem pensar, sem saber que pode ser diferente ou só porque parece mais curto usar o tipo sem modificador. As outras usam porque sabem que é a melhor opção naquela situação.

Um dos motivos talvez seja a [falta de unanimidade](http://blog.robertelder.org/signed-or-unsigned/). Tem [quem só vê problemas](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/avoid-unsigned-integers/).

[Documentação de tipos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

[Tipos extras menos conhecidos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: Não é somente uma questão de performance: Tipar as variáveis corretamente pode deixar o código mais legível e mais fácil de dar manutenção. Outro ponto interessante é que grande parte dos problemas computacionais podem ser resolvidos apenas com variáveis do tipo `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Um motivo é que não é muito prático porque o uso de tipos mais específicos acaba gerando muitos warnings na compilação. Por exemplo:

```
short x;
short y, z;

// normalmente aqui a compilação mostra warning, porque o resultado
// da soma y + z é um inteiro, que potencialmente pode ser maior
// que o maior valor de um short
x = y + z;
```

Além disso, *em geral* os ganhos de memória são desprezíveis, e em geral não há ganho de eficiência.

Answer (score 1):

A diferença de um tipo unsigned em resumo, é o tratamento ao primeiro bit no conjunto de bits de armazenamento desta variável na memória.
num sistema de 64 bits normalmente seria este unico 1 á direita:

10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Que seria tratado como sinal (normalmente 0=+ 1=-).
Este conjunto de bits suporta guardar 4294967295 possibilidades, que podem ser interpretados de duas principais maneiras.

0 ~ 4294967294  (*unsigned*)

-2147483646 ~ 2147483647  (*signed*)

O que na prática só importa a sua necessidade de implementação. Para a máquina tanto faz.

A grosso modo é isto.