# Modificador unsigned para o tipo inteiro em C

Tags: c, tipagem

As obras dizem que esse modificador faz com que a variável não aceite valores negativos, mas quando eu compilo esse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{

    unsigned int idade;
    idade = -3;    /* Não existe idade negativa */
    printf("Idade digitada : %u\n",idade);
}
```

Ele simplesmente ***aceita*** o ***valor negativo*** fornecido e exibe no console o valor `4294967293`, o compilador não deveria ter dito que não seria permitido esse valor a ser armazenado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, C não trabalha assim. C é uma linguagem criada para ser um Assembly de mais alto nível. Então a linguagem deve permitir o usuário fazer coisas inseguras.

C é uma linguagem fracamente tipada. Não confundir com [dinamicamente tipada](http://fracamente%20tipada). A maioria dos programadores confundem isso e tem bastante resposta bem votada aqui no site que estão erradas porque confundem isso.

Os dados e variáveis devem ter um tipo definido em tempo de compilação, por isso C é estaticamente tipada. Mas não há garantias que o valor seja adequado, muito menos que seja a intenção ter aquele valor. C é fracamente tipada por permitir coerção implícita. Ou seja, ele pega um espaço reservado para o dado, aplica um tipo nele e considera que o dado que está ali é daquele tipo, não importa se a intenção era essa.

Isso dá flexibilidade e ajuda na performance em várias situações. Mas reduz a robustez, uma característica que C nunca tentou ter.

Alguns compiladores fornecem a possibilidade de ligar um *warning* para avisar que isto está ocorrendo. Não faz parte do padrão e deve ser opcional. Um exemplo é o [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) do GCC.

Algo semelhante já foi respondido em [Como -1 pode ser maior que 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101).

Relacionado: [Utilização de modificadores de tipos de dado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152608/101)

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!