# Modificadores int, unsigned e signed na linguagem C

Tags: c, tipagem, int

Algoritmo "pega idade":

```
// idade deve sempre ser positiva, por isso vou usar unsigned
unsigned int t1;
printf("Digite sua idade:");
scanf("%d", &t1);
printf("Idade: %d", t1);
```

Dúvida: Mesmo eu entrando com um valor negativo, 2 `printf()` aparece negativo. Não compreendi a real utilização do modificador `unsigned` do `int`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando é utilizado o modificador **`%d`** você esta indicando um valor do tipo inteiro com sinal, neste caso negativo.
O modificador correto para sem sinal é **`%u`**. Internamente tanto o com sinal como o sem sinal acaba utilizando o mesmo numero de bits.
A diferença está que no caso com sinal, ele utiliza o bit mais significativo para indicar o sinal utilizado.

Comment: Não necessariamente usa-se um bit para o sinal. O padrão C não exige uma forma específica de armazenamento de sinal. O mais comum nem é esse tipo, e sim o complemento de 1s. [Algums detalhes em inglês aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239036/how-are-negative-signed-values-stored)

Comment: Complemento de 2 é o mais usado. Complemento de 1 é só os bits negados. Muitas vezes o oitavo bit é chamado de bit de sinal por força do hábito, pois ele estar ligado indica que o número é negativo, mas não necessariamente falar desse jeito indica que se está usando representação sinal magnitude. Eu trato desses três esquemas de representação [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248464/64969), incluindo alguns (não muitos) prós e contras

Comment: Por sinal, @PabloAlmeida, referência interessante

Comment: Boa resposta a sua. Confundi os dois aqui. Obrigado pela correção. :)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida eu também vivo confundido. Amanhã provavelmente eu não lembrarei qual o complemento de 2 e o do 1, mas hoje a resposta está correta

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer aceitar só positivos tem que filtrar adequadamente (`if (t1 >= 0)`).

O tipo `unsigned int` indica apenas que será um número sem sinal, não proíbe entrar um número negativo. É possível armazenar um número originalmente negativo nele onde ele perde o sinal e gera um número positivo bem diferente do que espera. Veja isto em [Como -1 pode ser maior que 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101).