# Como escolher corretamente um tipo de dado

Tags: c++, tipagem

Normalmente sempre programei sem dar muita atenção a isso, sempre usei `int`, `float`, `double` e etc., porém mais recentemente vi uma pessoa comentando que atualmente `float` é um tipo inútil por ser de 32 bits e que no lugar dele deveria ser utilizado `double` por ser 64 bits, lendo um livro sobre otimização em C++ descobri que uma operação de divisão pode levar muitos ciclos

> Multiplication and division take longer time. Integer multiplication
>   takes 11 clock cycles on Pentium 4 processors, and 3 - 4 clock cycles
>   on most other microprocessors. Integer division takes 40 - 80 clock
>   cycles, depending on the microprocessor

e que para acelerar isso deveria ser utilizado uma conversão para `unsigned int` como por exemplo:

```
// Example 7.4. Signed and unsigned integers
int a, b;
double c;
b = (unsigned int)a / 10; // Convert to unsigned for fast division
c = a * 2.5; // Use signed when converting to double
```

Então como eu escolho um tipo de dado de maneira "correta"?

Comment: Se unsigned não atende aos requisitos da aplicação não há por que utiliza-lo. A escolha do tipo de dados deve levar em consideração, prioritariamente, os requisitos da aplicação. Lembre-se de que otimização precoce é a mão de todos os males.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dar atenção aos tipos é algo de extrema importância em programação, especialmente em C++.

Se `float` fosse inútil ele não existira, certo? Ele é muito útil e espero que não ainda seja um programador de C++, onde ele é útil demais. Um `double` ocupa o dobro de espaço e em muitos casos isso faz uma diferença enorme. Além disto dependendo do tipo de plataforma um `double` pode ser mais lento por ter que fazer operações em duas partes. Claro que o `double` pode ser mais rápido em alguma plataforma, mas isto nem sempre acontece mesmo quando ela é 64 bits. Falar genericamente sobre isto não serve para nada, o que vale é o teste provando que é mais rápido na situação que precisa.

Se o `unsigned int` acelera a divisão também depende da plataforma onde está rodando, o ideal é usar o tipo mais adequado e quase sempre o ´int` está bom. Tipos sem sinal são mais difíceis de entender e tem comportamentos inesperados em algumas situações, por isso deve-se evitar. Ele pode ser usado sem problemas, não existe isso de nunca deva ser usado, só deve ser evitado se ele não é absolutamente necessário (há [questões a se observar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101)).

Se uma API que você usa tem esse tipo você tem que trabalhar com esse tipo, você não tem escolha, pelo menos de forma direta, claro que em alguns casos pode pegar o dado assim e transformar em `int` se desejar e for útil fazer isto (poderá haver uma conversão que tem um custo).

Só faça otimizações deste tipo se tem um problema de performance e sabe onde mexer. Além disto deve medir para ver se consegue ter mais performance, pode ser que não consiga, em muitos casos não conseguirá. E existem outras formas de otimizar isto. Divisão realmente é lenta, e tem técnicas efetivas para otimizar isto em muitos casos.

A escolha correta passa por domínio completo de tudo sobre computação, da linguagem, do compilador que usa, da plataforma que roda e experimentar muito. Não existe resposta mágica.

O o uso de `auto` não é para você não pensar no tipo que está usando, muito pelo contrário, é para dizer que o tipo não importa naquele caso, o que nem sempre é o que deseja. `auto`não é para economizar digitação ou aceitar qualquer tipo, é para dizer que o tipo que vier da expressão sendo atribuída na declaração é aceitável, e mesmo que ele mude para seu código está tudo ok. Você pensou sobre o tipo e estabeleceu que ele não importa.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente com C++ Moderno você pode optar por "auto" na maioria dos casos. 
No caso do float e double, realmente o double executa melhor as operações em equipamentos de 64bits, pois o alinhamento da memória acontece naturalmente e isso faz com que o processador execute em menos cíclos.
Já unsigned nunca deve ser usado, há um problema histórico de design e a recomendação atual é usar sempre int.

> "Unsigned integers are good for representing bitfields and modular
>   arithmetic. Because of historical accident, the C++ standard also uses
>   unsigned integers to represent the size of containers - many members
>   of the standards body believe this to be a mistake, but it is
>   effectively impossible to fix at this point. The fact that unsigned
>   arithmetic doesn't model the behavior of a simple integer, but is
>   instead defined by the standard to model modular arithmetic (wrapping
>   around on overflow/underflow), means that a significant class of bugs
>   cannot be diagnosed by the compiler. In other cases, the defined
>   behavior impedes optimization.
>
> That said, mixing signedness of integer types is responsible for an
>   equally large class of problems. The best advice we can provide: try
>   to use iterators and containers rather than pointers and sizes, try
>   not to mix signedness, and try to avoid unsigned types (except for
>   representing bitfields or modular arithmetic). Do not use an unsigned
>   type merely to assert that a variable is non-negative."

Aqui segue um exemplo de como vc pode testar os cíclos da sua função.
OBS: A parte do código para cálculo dos ciclos foi feito pelo Frederico L. Pissarra

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


// Mantém o timestamp inicial.
uint64_t __local_tsc;

#ifdef __x86_64__
#define REGS1 "rbx","rcx"
#define REGS2 "rcx"
#else
#ifdef __i386__
#define REGS1 "ebx","ecx"
#define REGS2 "ecx"
#else
#error cycle counting will work only on x86-64 or i386 platforms!
#endif
#endif

// Macro: Inicia a medição.
// Uso CPUID para serializar o processador aqui.
#define BEGIN_TSC do { \
  uint32_t a, d; \
\
  __asm__ __volatile__ ( \
    "xorl %%eax,%%eax\n" \
    "cpuid\n" \
    "rdtsc\n" \
    : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) :: REGS1 \
  ); \
\
  __local_tsc = ((uint64_t)d << 32) | a; \
} while (0)

// Macro: Finaliza a medição.
// NOTA: A rotina anterior usava armazenamento temporário
//       para guardar a contagem vinda de rdtscp. Ainda,
//       CPUID era usado para serialização (que parece ser inóquo!).
//       Obtive resultados melhores retirando a serialização e
//       devolvendo os constraints para EAX e EDX, salvando apenas ECX.
// PS:   rdtscp também serializa, deixando o CPUID supérfluo!
#define END_TSC(c) do { \
  uint32_t a, d; \
\
  __asm__ __volatile__ ( \
    "rdtscp\n" \
    : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) :: REGS2 \
  ); \
\
  (c) = (((uint64_t)d << 32) | a) - __local_tsc; \
} while (0)

// --------------------------------------------------------------------



template<typename T>
inline constexpr T length(T x, T y) {
  T len = x * x + y * y;
  return T(std::sqrt(len));
}

int main()
{
    const int ciclos = 900000;
    auto out{0.0};

    uint64_t t;
    uint64_t n = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ciclos; ++i)
    {
        BEGIN_TSC;
        out = length(3.4, 2.6);
        END_TSC(t);
        n += t;
    }
    std::cout << "Length: " << out << "\n";
    std::cout << "Média de cíclos do processador: " << n / ciclos << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso ainda não responde a questão de como posso descobrir qual tipo seria mais ideal, por exemplo olhe esta função da Vulkan API: vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties, um dos parâmetros é um unsigned int de 32-Bits, basicamente ele serve pra retornar o número de extensões disponíveis, então por que não usar simplesmente um int tradicional ao invés de usar um uint32_t ?

Comment: Quando você utiliza uma API como Vulkan você deve optar pelo formato que eles determinam. Se pede unsigned int, use isso. A opção deles está provavelmente ligado a performance e veja que no caso do Vulkan isso é relacionado a GPU que trabalha melhor com dados de 32bits, pois normalmente o objetivo principal é performance.
Na questão original você não havia comentado sobre isso, então eu pré supus que você estava falando de CPU.

Comment: Bom eu me refiro no geral mesmo