# Qual nome dado a um "overflow" de unsigned?

Tags: c, terminologia, tipagem

Considerando [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056828/11452150) gostaria de saber qual a nomenclatura de quando ocorre de tentar armazenar um valor maior do que o tipo `unsigned int` pode conter, pois o resultado será módulo `UINT_MAX`. Tem alguma nomenclatura específica quando ocorre de a variável não ter o valor que lhe foi atribuído? Tem nomenclatura específica quando o tipo é `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconheço qualquer termo específico oficial, ali usa uma expressão bastante comum que é "wrap around". De fato o que ocorre com tipos não sinalizados em C sequer pode ser chamado de *overflow*, inclusive por força de especificação não é isto que ocorre, não posemos chamar isto de *overflow* a não ser bem informalmente só para indicar que deu um erro sem se preocupar com o que aconteceu de fato. Veja mais sobre isso em [Como -1 pode ser maior que 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/101).

Comment: A nomenclatura seria "defined behavior:)"

Comment: *defined behavior* é muita coisa, não só isto.

Comment: @epx mas `1+1` e `UINT_MAX + 1` não são ambos _defined behavior_?

Comment: "defined behavior" é simplesmente "comporatmento definido" em inglês, e não precisa serquer ser lido como um termo técnico (apesar daqueles glossários enormes de definição de termos que encabeçam alguns documentos do tipo "RFC" poderem ter a expressão).

Simplesmente é um "comportamento definido" na especificação da linguagem que o número em questão "dá a volta", e o valor de NUM % (MAX_NUM + 1) é atribuido a variável.

Comment: Mas faz sentido usar "overflow" quando se está interessado em saber que o resultado não coube no destino, sem levar em conta as implicaçẽs disso, e "wrap around" descreve justamente a implicação disso em C. Em outra linguagem a consequência do "overflow" poderia ser uma exceção de  "ValueError", e assim por diante.