# Método read() da classe FileInputStream não está encontrando o fim do arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo

Este programa tem como finalidade copiar o conteúdo do arquivo de texto `origin.txt` e colá-lo no arquivo `destiny.txt`, sendo que a cada espaço lido no arquivo de origem, deve ser colado um hífen no arquivo de destino.

O laço `while` serve para ler caracteres do arquivo de origem até que chegue em seu fim, isto é, até que o método `read()` da classe `FileInputStream` retorne `-1`.

Porém, o laço não está lendo o arquivo de origem só até o seu fim, pois além de ler todos os caracteres do arquivo de origem e colá-los no arquivo de destino, ele também está lendo e colando bytes crus (Que no editor VSCode, aparecem só como sinais de interrogação). Aqui seguem algumas imagens que ilustram o  problema, e o programa:

Arquivo de origem - https://ibb.co/mqV5R8B 
Arquivo de destino (Onde será colado o conteúdo de origem) - https://ibb.co/mTJpZWq

```
import java.io.*;

public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int r = 0;

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("origin.txt");
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("destiny.txt");

    try {
      while (r != -1) {
        r = (char) fin.read();

        if (r == ' ')
          fout.write('-');
        else
          fout.write(r);
      }
    }

    catch (IOException exc) {
      System.out.println("Error while copying the files");
    }

    try {
      fin.close();
      fout.close();
    }

    catch (IOException exc) {
      System.out.println("Error while closing the files");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
r = (char) fin.read();
```

Mas antes de entender, considere o código abaixo:

```
int x = (char) -1;
System.out.println(x);
```

O código acima imprime `65535`. Isso acontece basicamente porque o literal `-1` é um `int` ([que em Java ocupa 32 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)), e ao fazer *cast* para `char` (que só tem 16 bits), os bits a mais são "perdidos".

Só que `int` é um tipo *signed* (com sinal, permite representar números positivos e negativos) e `char` é *unsigned* (sem sinal, só representa números positivos). Ou seja, apesar dos bytes serem os mesmos, a forma como eles são interpretados pode mudar. De forma bem resumida, o `-1` é representado com todos os bits iguais a 1 (segundo a [regra do complemento de 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48711/112052)). Ao fazer *cast* para `char`, os bits a mais são "perdidos", mas ainda sobram 16 bits iguais a 1. Mas como `char` é *unsigned*, isso é interpretado como o número 65535. E este é o valor que `r` recebe no seu código.

Ou seja, o seu `while` nunca termina, pois `r` nunca será igual a `-1`.

Para resolver, basta não fazer o *cast*:

```
while ((r = fin.read()) != -1) {
    if (r == ' ')
        fout.write('-');
    else fout.write(r);
}
```

Afinal, se você olhar na documentação, verá que [`read` retorna um `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) e [`write` recebe um `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)) como parâmetro. Não tem porque fazer o *cast*, até porque `int` e `char` são "intercambiáveis":

```
int x = ' ';
System.out.println(x); // 32 - valor do espaço na tabela ASCII
x = 32;
// imprime como char
System.out.println("[" + (char) x + "]"); // [ ]
System.out.println(x == ' '); // true
```

---

Outro detalhe é que a forma como você está fechando os arquivos está errada. Para garantir que eles sejam fechados, coloque as chamadas de `close` em um bloco `finally`:

```
FileInputStream fin = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try {
    fin = new FileInputStream("origin.txt");
    fout = new FileOutputStream("destiny.txt");
    int r;
    while ((r = fin.read()) != -1) {
        if (r == ' ')
            fout.write('-');
        else
            fout.write(r);
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    System.out.println("Error while copying the files");
} finally {
    try {
        if (fin != null)
            fin.close();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error while closing the files");
    }
    try {
        if (fout != null)
            fout.close();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error while closing the files");
    }
}
```

Assim você garante que os arquivos serão fechados ao final.

Ou, a partir do Java 7, prefira usar um bloco [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052), que já fecha tudo automaticamente, sem a necessidade de um bloco `finally`:

```
try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("origin.txt");
     FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("destiny.txt")) {
    int r;
    while ((r = fin.read()) != -1) {
        if (r == ' ')
            fout.write('-');
        else
            fout.write(r);
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    System.out.println("Error while copying the files");
}
```

---

Outra opção é usar um [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) para ler vários caracteres de uma vez, em vez de ler um a um:

```
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try (Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origin.txt"));
     Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("destiny.txt"))) {
    int lidos;
    while ((lidos = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lidos; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == ' ')
                buffer[i] = '-';
        }
        out.write(buffer, 0, lidos);
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    System.out.println("Error while copying the files");
}
```

Ou, se o arquivo não for muito grande, você também pode carregar todo o conteúdo em uma `String`, fazer a substituição e escrevê-la no outro arquivo:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


Path origin = Paths.get("origin.txt");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8; // escolha o encoding no qual o arquivo está
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(origin), charset);
Files.write(Paths.get("destiny.txt"), content.replaceAll(" ", "-").getBytes(charset));
```

Para o código acima, usei as classes do [pacote `java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)