# Como enviar 2 objetos do Controller para a View no C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Fiz uma consulta no banco de dados em 2 tabelas e salvei em 2 objetos no *controller*, mais só consigo enviar 1 objeto para a *view*.

```
// Controller
// Pego os dados do BD e salvo no objeto
var objPessoa = new PessoaAplic();
var dadosPessoa = objPessoa.ListarPorId(id);

// Pego os dados do BD e salvo no objeto
var objContato = new ContatoAplic();
var dadosContato = objContato.ListarPorId(dadosPessoa.IdPessoa);

return View(dadosPessoa);
```

Estou enviando o objeto `dadosPessoa` para a *view*, mais preciso enviar o  `dadosContato` também?

Como faço para enviar os 2 objetos para a *View*?

Comment: Realmente o que retornar o ListarPorId das duas classes ? Para que a resposta fica correta a sua pergunta! (Que tipo de dados elas retornar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode enviar via [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx), [ViewData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx) ou fazer um classe que contenha as informações (lista, item) pra ser consumido na sua View (`ViewModel`)

Pode utilizar de maneira correta qualquer uma das 3, por exemplo, carregar um *Dropdownlist* é muito simples com [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx). Se tu for passar muitas objetos de classes e quiser manter tudo isso padrão pode utilizar uma ViewModel que represente todas essas objetos de classes.

Mas, eu prefiro passar todas as formas para que você conheça e utilize de maneira adequada ...

***ViewBag***

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var objPessoa = new PessoaAplic();
    var dadosPessoa = objPessoa.ListarPorId(id);

    ViewBag.DadosPessoa = dadosPessoa;

    var objContato = new ContatoAplic();
    var dadosContato = objContato.ListarPorId(dadosPessoa.IdPessoa);

    ViewBag.DadosContato = dadosContato;

    return View();
}
```

***ViewData***

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var objPessoa = new PessoaAplic();
    var dadosPessoa = objPessoa.ListarPorId(id);

    ViewData.Add("DadosPessoa",dadosPessoa);

    var objContato = new ContatoAplic();
    var dadosContato = objContato.ListarPorId(dadosPessoa.IdPessoa);

    ViewData.Add("DadosContato",dadosContato);

    return View();
}
```

***ViewModel***

Classe responsável em trafegar as duas informações:

```
public class ViewModel

{
    public ViewModel(PessoaAplic pessoa, ContatoAplic contato)
    {
        Pessoa = pessoa;
        Contato = contato;

    }

    public PessoaAplic Pessoa { get; private set; }
    public ContatoAplic Contato { get; private set; }
}
```

Solução dentro do Controller

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var objPessoa = new PessoaAplic();
    var dadosPessoa = objPessoa.ListarPorId(id);

    var objContato = new ContatoAplic();
    var dadosContato = objContato.ListarPorId(dadosPessoa.IdPessoa);

    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(dadosPessoa, dadosContato);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Views:**

***ViewBag***

```
@{
    Layout = null;

    WebApplication2.Models.PessoaAplic Pessoa = (WebApplication2.Models.PessoaAplic)ViewBag.DadosPessoa;
    WebApplication2.Models.ContatoAplic Contato = (WebApplication2.Models.ContatoAplic)ViewBag.DadosContato;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***ViewData***

```
@{
    Layout = null;

    WebApplication2.Models.PessoaAplic Pessoa = (WebApplication2.Models.PessoaAplic)ViewData["DadosPessoa"];
    WebApplication2.Models.ContatoAplic Contato = (WebApplication2.Models.ContatoAplic)ViewData["DadosContato"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***ViewModel***

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.ViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;

    WebApplication2.Models.PessoaAplic Pessoa = Model.Pessoa;
    WebApplication2.Models.ContatoAplic Contato = Model.Contato;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Particularmente sou contra as abordagens `ViewBag` e `ViewData` por serem dinâmicas e permitirem anti-padrões entre as camadas. +1.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez particularmente falando as 3 abordagens são corretas e a pergunta se refere como devo proceder na passagem de valores, então, acredito que devemos passar todas e quaisquer informação para que o usuário nem a questão fiquem limitados aos nossos contras. O meu intuito foi mostrar todos os tipos ainda tem o TemData que não vem ao caso ...

Answer (score 9):

Crie um *ViewModel*:

```
public class PessoaContatosViewModel
{
    public PessoaAplic Pessoa { get; set; }
    public ContatoAplic Contato { get; set; }
}
```

Uso:

```
// Controller
// Pego os dados do BD e salvo no objeto
var viewModel = new PessoaContatosViewModel {
    Pessoa = objPessoa.ListarPorId(id),
    Contatos = objContato.ListarPorId(dadosPessoa.IdPessoa)
};

return View(viewModel);
```

Não esqueça de modificar a *View*:

```
@model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.PessoaContatosViewModel
```

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que encapsulá-los em outro objeto. Pode fazer isto de várias formas, uma delas é criar uma *viewmodel*:

```
public class PessoaViewModel {
    public Pessoa Pessoa {get; set;}
    public Contato Contato {get; set;}
}
```

Aí você passa:

```
return View(new PessoaViewModel {Pessoa = dadosPessoa , Contato = dadosContato});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ViewModel.cs).

O tipo das propriedades eu chutei, já que foi usado um `var` no código e não tenho como saber qual é o resultado das operações realizadas. Adapte ao tipo necessário.

Comment: Realmente essa facilidade de usar `var` atrapalhar bastante o saber. A pessoas deveria repensar e não utilizar `var` a dados que tem tipo. +1

Comment: @Cezar o `var` em si não é ruim, mas tem um lugar onde ele não deveria ser usado, e é justamente onde ele usou. Não tem como saber o tipo que o método retorna sem estar no IDE: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101

Comment: é bem isso que você disse ali é lugar de usar a tipagem correta, inclusive legitimidade de código !!! seria bem melhor usar o seu tipo, já até pedi para ele enviar os tipos se sim fazer eu altero a questão para que fica correta a pergunta!