# Carregar view por parâmetro

Tags: c#

Como eu faço para chamar uma view passando um parâmetro?

Tipo, `if parametro = 1 <h1>Teste1</h1> else <h1>Teste2</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Mediante a resposta da pergunta : [Como enviar 2 objetos do Controller para a View no C# ASP.NET MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91026/33749), faça o seguinte

No seu *controller*:

```
public ActionResult View()
{
    ViewBag.Parametro = 1;
    return View();
}
```

E na sua View:

```
@if (((int)ViewBag.Parametro) == 1) {
    <h1>Teste1</h1>
} else {
    <h1>Teste2</h1>
}
```