# Como passar variáveis do Controller para a View no ASP.NET MVC 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou bastante acostumado com o MVC em PHP onde consigo passar os valores para a *view* a partir do *controller* da seguinte forma:

```
public function Index(Users user)
{
    return View('index')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Ou para retornar erros de validação:

```
public function Index()
{
    return View('index')
        ->withErrors(['Erro1', 'Erro2']);
}
```

Como eu posso fazer o mesmo no C#? por exemplo, eu possuo a função que recebe os valores de E-mail e Senha de um formulário, verifica se o usuário existe e caso não exista, retorna uma variável com o erro.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Attempt(string email, string password, Admins db)
{
    Admins admin = db.admins.Where(model => model.email == email).FirstOrDefault(); 

    // return view().with("error", "test1"); ????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente usa-se `ViewBag` ou `ViewData`. O que for criado no controlador poderá ser acessado na visão.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Attempt(string email, string password, Admins db) {
    Admins admin = db.admins.Where(model => model.email == email).FirstOrDefault(); 
    ViewBag.Error = "test1"; //ou ViewData["Error"] = "test1";
    return View();
}
```

Na *view* vai usar assim:

```
@ViewBag.Error
ou @ViewData["Error"]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/VariableControllerToView.cs).

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91021/101).

Answer (score 0):

A maneira correta de enviar erros de validação do *Controller* para a *View* é através do comando [`ModelState.AddModelError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
[HttpPost]
public void Attempt(string email, string password, Admins db)
{
    Admins admin = db.admins.FirstOrDefault(model => model.email == email); 

    if (admin == null) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário não é admin.")
    }
}
```

O dicionário [`ModelState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) representa não apenas o resultado de todas as validações envolvendo a requisição, mas também o estado do *Model*, o *binding* de suas variáveis e informações sobre o formulário. É preenchido, em boa parte, pelo próprio *pipeline* MVC, mas pode ser também preenchido pelo programador, como neste caso.

`AddModelError` possui também uma forma que aceita uma exceção ao invés de uma mensagem de erro. O primeiro parâmetro corresponde ao nome do campo em que a mensagem de validação deve aparecer (normalmente combinado com [jQuery.Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), que já vem instalado por padrão) O preenchimento do primeiro parâmetro é opcional, já que a mensagem de validação pode se referir ao *Model* inteiro, como no exemplo. Neste caso, deve-se usar [`@Html.ValidationSummary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx) para exibir as mensagens de validação levantadas sem campos específicos.

*ViewBag* e *ViewData* não são boas escolhas para validação porque não possuem qualquer padronização de dados e não são preenchidos automaticamente pelo *framework*