# ASP.NET.MVC Dúvida básica - Cadastro com "subform"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou trabalhando em meu primeiro projeto ASP.MVC com C# e estou brincando com o cadastro de alunos.
Na página de cadastro do aluno há um CheckBox que quando marcado (imaginei eu) deve habilitar a adição de alergias que o aluno possa ter. Veja o banco (bem básico):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um WindowsForm eu teria um subform de alergias associado ao formulário do aluno, para que o usuário selecionasse quantas alergias quisesse em um grid ou em um listbox.
Como resolver isso em desenvolvimento web? Estou confuso, porque a view está associada a um modelo, no caso aluno. Seu botão de submit grava na tabela Alunos... **Então como, na página de cadastro do aluno, listar os itens da tabela Alergias para o usuário selecionar os que deseja. E depois como cadastrar na tabela AlergiasAlunos ao submeter a página Aluno?**

---

***Update-01:***

Tenho agora este modelo:

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Pessoa()
    {
        this.AlergiasPessoas = new HashSet<AlergiasPessoas>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AlergiasPessoas> AlergiasPessoas { get; set; }
}
```

Este Controller:

```
// POST: Pessoas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,nome")] Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pessoa.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pessoa);
    }

    // GET: Pessoas/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoa.Find(id);
        if (pessoa == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(pessoa);
    }
```

E está View:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Personalizei ela com esta listbox:

```
<!-- Item adicionado para permitir selecionar Alergias-->
    @{ CadastroAluno.Models.TESTEEntities Banco = new CadastroAluno.Models.TESTEEntities(); }
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ID">Possui Alergia?</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="ExibeItem(this.checked)" htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="Oculta" style="display:none"> 
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlergiasPessoas, "AlergiasPessoas", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AlergiasPessoas, new SelectList(Banco.AlergiasPessoas, "ID", "ID_Alergia"),
                      htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlergiasPessoas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- - -->
```

e com este java:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ExibeItem(CheckBox) {
    if (CheckBox == false) {            
        document.getElementById('Oculta').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Oculta').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

mas a ListBox continua vazia... Como preencher ela com os itens cadastrados na tabela Alergia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um método para resolver esse problema é:

Na View, dentro do form, cria uma `div` que contenha todos os elementos de alergia, e atribua um `css` para controlar quando ela deve aparecer ou não, este `css` pode ser um `visibility: hidden`, ou um `display:none`.

E você controla o click em cima do *checkbox* através de um [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery). Assim, quando o *checkbox* for marcado você faz com que esta `div` que contem as informações de alergia aparecer.

Quanto aos dados enviados da *View* para o *Controller*,ao clicar no botão de enviar, voce faz com que o *Model* referente a essa *View* passe os valores que serão tratados diretamente na *Controller*

**EDITADO:**

Da mesma forma que voce está passando informação view pra controller, tem como passar informação da controller para view [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91021/como-enviar-2-objetos-do-controller-para-a-view-no-c-asp-net-mvc). Assim voce pode levar a lista de alergias para a view e, pelo que estou vendo, está usando Razor, portanto voce pode fazer uma lista de checkboxes com as alergias existentes, [veja como aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach). Acho que daqui em diante voce consegue fazer, já que já sabe passar informações da view para controller. Se tiver ainda alguma duvida é só comentar e/ou modificar a pergunta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Um ! Sua resposta me deu um norte. Mas como disse sou novato nessa coisa de views... Se puder ir devagar comigo...
Bom usando a mágica do EntityFramework DatabaseFirst o Visual Studio criou os modelos das 3 tabelas para mim (só tive que adicionar um Id na AlergiasPessoas). Depois o Scaffold criou pra mim o Controller e as Views da tabela/modelo Pessoa. Peguei então a View Create como exemplo. Vou Editar o post e adicionar esta nova parte, ok?