# Atualizar todos os dados da View via Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Eu preciso atualizar todos os dados da minha `View`, eu chamo essa função para atualizar, passando o parâmetro empresa:

```
function CarregaCaixa() {
var Empresa = $("#EmpresaFiltroId").val();

var url = "/Caixa/CarregaCaixa";
$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , data: { empresaId: Empresa }
    , datatype: "html"
    , success: function (data) {
        $("#model").html(data.model);
    }
});
```

}

E no `controller` eu retorno assim:

```
        var model = new CaixaViewModel();
        model.EmpresaList = new SelectList(empresa, "Id", "Value");
        model.ValorSaida = ValorSaida.ToString("C2");
        model.ValorEntrada = ValorEntrada.ToString("C2");
        model.EmpresaFiltro = new SelectList(empresa, "Id", "Value");
        model.EmpresaFiltroId = empresaId;
        model.CaixaList = union;
        return Json(new { model });
```

Como posso retornar os dados todos de uma vez, estou atualizando os dados da minha `View`, tem alguma maneira sem precisar passar campo por campo.

Comment: Mariana, você viu esse post? ->

Como enviar 2 objetos do Controller para a View no C# ASP.Net MVC? -
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91021/como-enviar-2-objetos-do-controller-para-a-view-no-c-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @FabioIn eu não queria enviar um ou outro objetos, queria atualizar a View inteira.  Vou dar uma olhada no post. Da forma do post, é por `ViewData` ou `ViewBag`. Queria ver se teria algo que atualizasse todos os dados.

Comment: Eu uso a viewmodel, p atualizar a View, funciona no load, só que preciso que o usuário passe um parâmetro, para então filtrar os dados e atualizar novamente, com o filtro, conforme o parâmetro fornecido.

Comment: Você precisa retornar a `View` pelo `controller` a técnica seria com `PartialView` e atualizar esse trecho de `View` pelo controller ... eu acho que é isso que você precisa?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu não queria utilizar `PartialView`, queria atualizar tudo em uma única pagina, pois para a `PartialView` eu iria precisar fazer uma outra ´page´ para atualizar.

Comment: Lembrando que utilizo `core`

Comment: Eu faria um partido views, mas se não quiser precisa trabalhar com framework reativo angular, Reactjs ou vue