# Duvida sobre como fazer um cadastro

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal, bom sou novo aqui, então peço desculpas por qualquer coisa!

A minha duvida é:

Eu tenho uma tabela de equipamentos, uma de software e uma associativa  equipamento-software. 
A relação ficou (Equipamento) 1 → N (EquipamentoSoftware) N ← 1 (Software),
onde um equipamento pode ter vários software, mas aquele equipamentoSoftware está só naquele equipamento, etc;

Eu consegui fazer a parte do crud do equipamento muito boa, porem para cadastrar um Software no equipamento, só consegui fazer em um crud separado.

Gostaria de saber como faço para cadastrar o Equipamento e um equipamentoSoftware (Um software no equipamento) na mesma View.

Vou postar meu código

Model Equipamento:

```
public partial class tblEquipamento
{
  public tblEquipamento()
  {
    this.tblEquipamentoSoftware = new HashSet<tblEquipamentoSoftware>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int equIdEquipamento { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o NIP do equipamento!")]
  [Display(Name = "NIP")]
  public string equNip { get; set; }
  public string equNumSerie { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<tblEquipamentoSoftware> tblEquipamentoSoftware { get; set; }
}
```

Model software:

```
public partial class tblSoftware
{
  public tblSoftware()
  {
    this.tblEquipamentoSoftware = new HashSet<tblEquipamentoSoftware>();
  }
  [Key]
  public int sofIdSoftware { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Software")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome do Software!")]
  public string sofNome { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<tblEquipamentoSoftware> tblEquipamentoSoftware { get; set; }
}
```

Model EquipamentoSoftware (associativa):

```
public partial class tblEquipamentoSoftware
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [Display(Name = "Equipamento")]
        public int eqsIdEquipamento { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [Display(Name= "Software")]
        public int eqsIdSoftware { get; set; }

        public virtual tblEquipamento tblEquipamento { get; set; }
        public virtual tblSoftware tblSoftware { get; set; }
    }
```

Cadastrar tudo de uma vez, sem precisar separa um equipamento do equipamentoSoftware. Por favor galera me ajudem e se tiver algo errado, me avisem que eu edito.
Estou fazendo no c# junto com o entity framework e pelo ADO.NET
Obrigado!

Quero juntar esses dois cruds em um unico formulário ou view

Crud do Equipamento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Crud do equipamentoSoftware:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia mostrar que crud fez e uma representação visual do resultado pretendido?

Comment: Posso sim, colocarei a imagem

Comment: Vc esta querendo que na hora de cadastrar um equipamento, vc já quer cadastrar o "equipamentoSoftware" junto? Cadastrar tudo de uma vez, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quero cadastrar os dois em unico formulario!

Comment: @user7845, voce precisa fazer uma ViewModel onde ela ira receber as propriedades de ambos os cadastro que quer fazer, assim voce consegue chamar essa model na sua view e colocar os campos para serem preenchidos conforme sua necessidade

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91021/como-enviar-2-objetos-do-controller-para-a-view-no-c-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom isso se parece muito com um cadastro de item em um pedido, irei fazer de um modo bem resumido, porém não é o único jeito de se fazer ok?

Primeiro em seu `controller` de Equipamento vamos fazer ele retornar um `Json` da seguinte maneira:

Obs.: o modo get fica da mesma maneira, quando você criar pelo `MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework`.

O seu método `create POST` será assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(tblEquipamento tblEquipamento)
{ 
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.tblEquipamento.Add(tblEquipamento);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
     return Json(new { Resultado = tblEquipamento.equIdEquipamento }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Agora no na sua view create do Equipamento você poderá apagar o `@using (Html.BeginForm())` e adicionará os seguintes códigos:

Um botão para salvar o equipamento:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
       <a href="#" onclick="SalvarEquipamento();" class="btn btn-info">Salvar</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

este botão acionará uma função no seu JavaScript que salvará seu equipamento para criar um `Id`

Logo abaixo desse código você irá colocar uma `div` que será "invisível" de início, mas será nela que aparecerá o formulário para cadastrar o software desejado!

```
<div id="divSoftwares" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Feito todo esse procedimento,você irá criar um arquivo `.js`, nele iremos colocar todo nosso JavaScript. Chamei o meu de `Equipamento.js`, você pode dar o nome que quiser, ok?

O método que irá salvar o equipamento será desse modo, usaremos Ajax:

```
function SalvarEquipamento() {

    var nip = $("#equNip").val();

    var serie = $("#equNumSerie").val();

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Equipamento/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    var headers = {};
    var headersadr = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    headersadr['__ResquestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

    var url = "/Equipamento/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "json"
        , headers: headersadr
        , data: {
            equIdEquipamento: 0, equNip: nip, equNumSerie: serie, __RequestVerificationToken: token
        }
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.Resultado > 0) {
                ListarSoftwares(data.Resultado);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Obs.: Este token faz referência ao `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

Ainda em nosso `Equipamento.js` você fará um método para fazer a listagem dos softwares que estão sendo cadastrados junto aquele equipamento.

```
function ListarSoftwares(idEquipamento) {
    var url = "/EquipamentoSoftware/ListarSoftwares";
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: idEquipamento}
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            var divSoftwares = $("#divSoftwares");
            divSoftwares.empty();
            divSoftwares.show();
            divSoftwares.html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Feito isso você irá criar um `Controller` para o seu EquipamentoSoftware, pode criar um `controller Empty` mesmo.
Nele você colocará um `ActionResult` que será responsável por fazer a chamada do formulário  do `EquipamentoSoftware`, ficará assim:

```
public ActionResult ListarSoftwares(int id)
{
   var lista = db.tblEquipamentoSoftware.Where(t => t.tblEquipamento.equIdEquipamento == id);
   ViewBag.eqsIdSoftware = new SelectList(db.tblSoftware, "sofIdSoftware", "sofNome");
   ViewBag.Equipamento = id;
   return PartialView(lista);
 }
```

Então você criará uma `view ListarSoftware`, ela será do tipo `List`, ok?

```
@model IEnumerable<SistemaCadastroAtivo.Models.tblEquipamentoSoftware>

<div>
    <h4>Softwares</h4>
    <hr/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Software</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("eqsIdSoftware", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Software"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tipo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="Tipo" name="Tipo" placeholder="Informe L p/ Licença ou I p/ instalado" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <a href="#" onclick="SalvarSoftwaresEquipamento();" class="btn btn-info">Adicionar Software</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="idEquipamento" value="@ViewBag.Equipamento" />


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.eqsTipo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblEquipamento.equNip)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblSoftware.sofNome)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.eqsTipo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblEquipamento.equNip)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblSoftware.sofNome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Nela você está trazendo o formulário do EquipamentoSoftware e também uma tabela para a listagem dos softwares que estão sendo cadastrados a este equipamento.

Você deve ter percebido um botão para salvar os softwares, logo você fará o método no `Equipamento.js` da seguinte maneira:

```
function SalvarSoftwaresEquipamento() {
    debugger;
    var idSoftware = $("#Software").val();
    var tipo = $("#Tipo").val();
    var idEquipamento = $("#idEquipamento").val();

    var url = "/EquipamentoSoftware/SalvarSoftwares";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { idSoftware: idSoftware, tipo: tipo, idEquipamento: idEquipamento }
        , type: "GET"
        , datatype: "json"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.Resultado > 0) {
                debugger;
                ListarSoftwares(idEquipamento);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

E por fim lá em seu `EquipamentoSoftwareController` você fará isso:

```
public ActionResult SalvarSoftwares(int idEquipamento, int idSoftware, string tipo)
{
   var equipamentoSoftware = new tblEquipamentoSoftware()
   {
     tblEquipamento = db.tblEquipamento.Find(idEquipamento), 
     tblSoftware = db.tblSoftware.Find(idSoftware),
     eqsTipo = tipo
   };

    db.tblEquipamentoSoftware.Add(equipamentoSoftware);
    db.SaveChanges();   
    return Json(new { Resultado = equipamentoSoftware.eqsIdEquipamento }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Obs.: É necessário que você ja tenha feito o `crud` dos softwares, para poder trazer para a view do equipamento.

Sua tela ficará desse modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em salvar aparecerá o formulário do EquipamentoSoftware:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z7BYLM3Lus