# Como funciona um método dentro de outro? E.g: service.metodo(argumentos).execute();

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método

Eu não estou entendendo isso esse método dentro de outro método alguém me explica isso?

Outro exemplo da minha dúvida:

```
ImageKeywords keywords =  service.getImageKeywords(image, forceShowAll, knowledgeGraph).execute();
```

Ele tem um método que chama outro método dentro dele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há um método dentro do outro, há uma sequência de métodos.

Com o objeto `service`chama o método `getImageKeywords()` passando alguns argumentos. Ele produzirá um resultado (em geral os métodos retornam alguma coisa), esse resultado é um objeto que pode invocar outros métodos, no caso está invocando o `execute()` no objeto retornado pelo `getImageKeywords()`. O resultado de `execute()` é que será guardado na variável `keywords`.

Esse código poderia ser escrito assim (ou quase, usei [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101), que ainda não tem em Java, porque não sei o tipo do método):

```
var temp = service.getImageKeywords(image, forceShowAll, knowledgeGraph);
ImageKeywords keywords = temp.execute();
```

Exemplo mais visível:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String x = teste().toString(); //teste retorna um inteiro 42 que é usado pelo toString
    System.out.println(x); //x já é uma string "42"
}
public static Integer teste() {
    return 42;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PfDGN1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tndccswn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Methods.java).

Uma coisa que as pessoas não costumam percebem é que variáveis servem para guardar valores intermediários. Há casos que elas são necessárias, ou pelo menos mais vantajosas, mas nem sempre elas precisam ser usadas. Um valor intermediário de uma expressão pode ser usado direto onde seja necessário sem o uso de variável.

Uma expressão é, geralmente, composta de sub-expressões que produzem valores intermediários. Pura matemática.

Comment: Entendi! Que ótimo exemplo. Mas me surgiu uma dúvida, @bigown, sempre terá que retornar algo para fazer a chamada a outro método?

Comment: Sim, e é óbvio que o método seguinte terá que estar disponível para o objeto retornado. Posso melhorar a resposta, tem o contexto onde este código está sendo usado? Tem a documentação de `getImageKeywords`?

Comment: Não precisa não, eu entedi.