# Existe diferenças na performance de variáveis implicitamente e explicitamente declaradas?

Tags: c#, vb.net, variáveis, desempenho

Existe diferenças na **performance** de variáveis explicitamente declaradas?

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>();
```

E implicitamente declaradas?

```
var lista = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47383/quando-usar-var-em-c, apesar que existe muita polêmica no assunto, e eu prefiro explicito ...

Comment: Não me leve a mau @viniciusbrasil sobre a duplicata, apesar que poderia até deixar outros opinarem.

Comment: Não há nenhum ganho ou perda de performance em usar o `var` porque os tipos da variáveis declaradas pelo `var` são definidas em tempo de execução, ou seja `var v = 10;` é o mesmo que `int v = 10;` e o código assembly será o mesmo.