# Diferenças entre declarações de variáveis em C#

Tags: c#, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Qual a diferença entre essas declarações:

```
Classex xx = new Classex();
var xx = new Classex();
Classex xx;
```

Se no final consigo usar tudo da mesma forma (métodos, propriedades...)

Ex.:

Eu crio uma lista: `List<Classex> lstx = new List<Classex>();`

Adiciono alguns valores: `lstx.Add(...)`

Depois quero pegar alguns valores dessa lista e inserir em outra, qual a melhor maneira de se fazer:

```
var lstx_filtrada = new List<Classex>;,
List<Classex> lstx_filtrada= new List<Classex>;
List<Classex> lstx_filtrada;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sobre o uso do `var` ou o tipo explicitamente já foi em respondi em [Quando usar var em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101), por este motivo acho desnecessário postar aqui os dois primeiros exemplos.

A terceira opção você não consegue usar da mesma forma, se tentar usar o objeto uma exceção `NullReferenceException` será lançada porque não há um objeto instanciado para a variável. Só poderá ser usado se mais pra frente inicializar o objeto de alguma forma. Sem um objeto formado qualquer acesso a um membro da instância falhará porque não tem nada para acessar. Note que o acesso aos membros da classe (portanto os estáticos) é possível porque não depende de instância.

Em C# 8 passa ser proibida essa forma de declaração, a não ser que mantenha desligado a verificação de objeto nulo, ou declare assim:

```
Classex? xx;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/NullDeclaration.cs).

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é:

#### 1º Caso

> Classex xx = new Classex();

Você criou uma variável `xx` do tipo `Classex` que já foi inicializada com uma nova instância de `Classex`.

#### 2º Caso

> var xx = new Classex();

A mesma coisa do anterior, só que quando você declarou `var` você atribuiu ao compilador a responsabilidade de 'descobrir' qual é o tipo de `xx`, como já esclarecido [na pergunta e resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47383/quando-usar-var-em-c) [referenciada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47386/78713).

Tecnicamente as duas declarações são iguais, mas uma delas (a que usa o `var`) é uma forma simplificada de codificar. Se a variável está sendo criada naquele momento e já recebendo o seu valor o compilador infere que o tipo dela será o mesmo tipo do objeto que ela está recebendo.

#### 3º Caso

> Classex xx;

Como no primeiro, você especificou explicitamente o tipo da variável. Mas, em qualquer tentativa de uso sem uma inicialização resultará em erro (em alguns casos de compilação inclusive), como já explicado na [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/302946/78713).