# Qual o tipo da expressão quando operandos do operador condicional ("ternário") possuem tipos diferentes?

Tags: java, tipagem

Quis explorar o que acontece no Java quando não sabemos o tipo de dado que vamos receber. Como eu vi que essa classe `Scanner` tem checadores de tipo, testei ele.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
var number = scan.hasNextInt() ? scan.nextInt() : "Você digitou um número real";
System.out.println(number);
```

Nessa variável `number`, a IDE mostra que o tipo dela é `Serializable && Comparable`.

Se eu mudar para:

```
var number = scan.hasNextInt() ? scan.nextInt() : scan.nextDouble();
```

Agora a IDE mostra que o tipo seria `double`, ignorando que poderia ser `int` também.

O que está acontecendo nesse caso?

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. Eu já respondi sobre isto em alguma linguagem, mas não vou conseguir achar. A variável só pode ter um tipo e ele é sabido. Leia a documentação dos métodos usados, eles não fazem o que acha que faz. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html. Provavelmente o `var` também não faz o que pensa. Eu já respondi em C# mas é a mesma coisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101. O `|` também parece que não é o que deseja usar.

Comment: @Maniero Quando vc tem `var x = condicao ? v1 : v2` e os tipos de `v1` e `v2` são diferentes, o tipo da expressão é o "supertipo ancestral em comum" (_least upper bound_) entre `v1` e `v2` (por isso entre um `Integer` e uma `String` o "supertipo comum" mostrado pela IDE é `Serializable & Comparable` - claro que em _runtime_ o tipo será inteiro ou `String`, mas em _compile time_ a IDE mostra o _least upper bound_). Quando ambos são tipos primitivos (`int` e `double`, por exemplo), há outras regras envolvidas, mas está tudo na especificação da linguagem.

Comment: Enfim, não encontrei pergunta semelhante no site, e acho que esta é válida - talvez o `|` seja uma "distração" e possa ser retirado ou corrigido, ou o exemplo como um todo possa ser melhorado, mas sobre o comportamento geral (expressão ternária com operandos de tipos diferentes), é algo especificado pela linguagem e implementado pelas IDE's, com regras especificadas (meio complicadas, é verdade) que podem ser perfeitamente explicadas. Por isso votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A IDE está mostrando o tipo da expressão como um todo, mas vamos por partes.

---

O nome do operador `? :` (que comumente é chamado de "ternário"), segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), é "*conditional operator*" (operador condicional). No link já citado está a definição dele, que descreve as regras para determinar o tipo da expressão como um todo.

Basicamente, o tipo da expressão vai depender dos operandos. Lembrando que este operador recebe 3 operandos: `op1 ? op2 : op3`. O primeiro sempre deve ser `boolean`, então o que varia são os outros dois.

E também há diferença quando ambos (o segundo e terceiro operandos) são numéricos e quando pelo menos um deles não é. Vamos ver cada caso separadamente.

---

## Quando ambos os operandos são numéricos

No caso em que o segundo e terceiro operandos são expressões numéricas (por exemplo, um `int` e um `double`, que é o caso em que você usou `nextInt()` e `nextDouble()`), são aplicadas as regras [desta tabela](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-B). No caso de um `int` e um `double`, o resultado indicado é `bnp(int,double)`.

`bnp` é a operação de *binary numeric promotion*, que é descrita [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), e uma das regras diz que se um dos operandos é `double`, a expressão toda será "promovida" para este tipo. Por isso quando há um `int` e um `double` envolvidos, o resultado é um `double`.

Ou seja, neste código:

```java
static int lerInt(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("ler int");
    return scan.nextInt();
}
static double lerDouble(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("ler double");
    return scan.nextDouble();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    var number = scan.hasNextInt() ? lerInt(scan) : lerDouble(scan);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Mesmo se eu digitar um número inteiro (por exemplo, `1`), o resultado será um `double`. A saída do código é:

```
ler int
1.0
```

Ou seja, o `Scanner` detectou que tem um número inteiro a ser lido, mas devido às regras já explicadas, o tipo da expressão (e portanto da variável `number`) acaba sendo `double` - ou seja, o valor inteiro `1` acaba sendo "promovido" para `double` (repare que ao imprimir, o resultado foi `1.0`, que é o padrão para quando se imprime um `double` - se o tipo fosse `int`, iria imprimir apenas `1`).

---

## Quando pelo menos um dos operandos não é numérico

Só para esclarecer, a [já citada especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) define 3 casos principais para o tipo de uma expressão com o operador condicional:

- se o segundo e terceiro operandos são expressões *booleanas*, a expressão é uma *boolean conditional expression* (e o seu tipo é `boolean`)
- se o segundo e terceiro operandos são expressões numéricas, cai nas regras já citadas acima
- caso contrário, a expressão é uma *reference conditional expression*

Ou seja, a expressão `scan.hasNextInt() ? scan.nextInt() : "Você digitou um número real"` cai no terceiro caso.

[A definição de *reference conditional expression* também está especificada](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3), e de forma resumida, o tipo da expressão acaba sendo o *lub* (*least upper bound*) entre os tipos do segundo e terceiro operando. Seria algo como o "supertipo ancestral em comum". E quando um dos tipos é primitivo, antes é feito o *boxing* do mesmo (ex: quando um operando é `int` e o outro é `String`, primeiro é feito o *boxing* do `int` para `Integer`, e depois determina-se o `lub(Integer, String)`).

[A definição de *least upper bound* também está descrita na especificação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4), e basicamente procura-se "*a shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype*". No caso de `Integer` e `String`, o resultado é `Serializable && Comparable` (interfaces que ambas as classes implementam, e portanto o "ancestral em comum" entre elas, já que não há outras superclasses que ambas compartilhem).

---

**É claro** que em *runtime* a variável assumirá apenas um dos tipos. Mas em *compile time* a IDE não tem como saber qual dos dois tipos será aplicado, e por isso ela acaba mostrando o tipo resultante da expressão (quando os operandos são números, o resultado foi `double`, e quando há outros tipos envolvidos, o resultado é o *least upper bound* entre eles).

Este tipo é inferido ("adivinhado", segundo as regras já explicadas) porque você está declarando a variável com `var`, que é um mecanismo que faz com que você não precise declarar o tipo explicitamente, deixando para o compilador inferir esta informação, baseando-se no contexto (no seu caso específico, é o tipo resultante do operador condicional).

---

Ver também: [Local Variable Type Inference with Conditional (Ternary) Operator of Different Types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55938289).

Comment: Sabia que ao perguntar estaria mexendo num vespeiro complexo haha.

Eu usei a keyword `var` exatamente pra saber os tipos que seriam inferidos. O do double foi mais simples perceber que é apenas uma regra do java e não tem o que fazer.
Agora essa de classes é uma volta bem louca né haha pra achar uma intercessão entre as classes.

Obrigado pela explicação super completa. Vou salvar aqui para posterioridade.

Comment: E vale lembrar que os dois casos são "regras do Java", já que ambos estão definidos na especificação da linguagem :-)