# Parâmetro de qualquer tipo em método

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros, tipagem

Estou construindo um método e gostaria que ele se estendesse em qualquer tipo. Por enquanto estou usando `string` mas gostaria que o mesmo funcionasse para `int`, `float`, `double` e `datetime`.

```
public static bool isNotNull(string AnyTypeValue) // nao funcionar var
{

   //tratamentos por tipo
}
```

Comment: Depende do que o método fizer, e de como ele vai ser usado. Sem mais contexto, é impossivel ajudar. Com certeza, o metodo `isNotNull` é fictício e não o código real.

Comment: É, certamente verificar se um `int` é `null` não faz muito sentido.

Comment: verifico se o int  nao é = 0, uso este método para fazer uma espécie de validação pra todos os dados do formulário antes de dar insert no banco

Comment: Valor nulo e valor zero são coisas bem diferentes. Claro que você até pode fazer esta comparação mas é uma mistura de conceitos. No exemplo que você deu pode ser um enorme problema não permitir a inserção de valor 0 no banco de dados.

Comment: Entendo, porem nos casos em que usamos por aqui nao podemos inserir 0 ou NUll. A ideia do metodo é poder verificar se qualquer item é uma data valida, ou se o valor numerico é >0 ou se a string nao esta nula/vazia/espacos em branco

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não recomendo fazer isso em C# mas pode usar [`dynamic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que permite que a variável tenha seu tipo determinado em tempo de execução:

```
public static bool isNotNull(dynamic AnyTypeValue) {
    //tratamentos por tipo
}
```

Outra forma é usando [`object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) que é o ancestral de todos os tipos da linguagem:

```
public static bool isNotNull(object AnyTypeValue) {
    //tratamentos por tipo
}
```

Veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101) para entender melhor as diferenças entre o uso de uma forma e outra. O `var` tem propósito completamente diferente.

Ainda existe uma possibilidade que considero bem melhor e recomendo ela, se for possível. É o uso de [tipos genéricos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
public static bool isNotNull<T>(T AnyTypeValue) {
    //não precisa fazer tratamentos por tipo
}
```

Essa forma mantém a tipagem integral. Neste caso o `T` será substituído pelo tipo que você mandar como argumento na chamada do método (pode ser inferido em certas circunstâncias). Não vou explicar todo o funcionamento dos métodos genéricos porque não é o foco da pergunta.

Talvez você queira até mesmo restringir para determinados tipos. Se vai verificar se o objeto não é nulo, então talvez queira fazer isto apenas com classes:

```
public static bool isNotNull<T>(T AnyTypeValue) where T : class {
   //se tiver que fazer tratamento por tipo, algo está errado
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/AnyType.cs).

Se você tem uma especialização, ou seja, tem que fazer algo específico para cada tipo, então provavelmente você deveria ter vários métodos fazendo sobrecarga para cada tipo.

Eu evitaria os dois primeiros sempre que possível, especialmente o primeiro - é possível que o uso de `object` nem seja problemático se o método for simples e fizer coisas que realmente não importa o tipo que ele é. Eles até são úteis em determinadas situações mas distorcem a filosofia da linguagem.

É possível que você esteja acostumado com linguagens dinâmicas onde isso é normal. Em linguagens estáticas, não é que esteja errado e não possa fazer, mas a filosofia é separar cada manipulação em seu próprio método. Só deve usar uma método genérico - no sentido conceitual, em oposição de método específico - se a operação é efetivamente genérica.

Comment: Excelente, pra finalizar considere citar o uso de sobrecarga do método.

Comment: Estava começando fazer isto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, melhorou a qualidade do que estava fazendo em 100%

Comment: Sobrecarga de metodo não conhecia. Sensacional esta metodologia