# Por que os outros tipos de variáveis não são substituídos por dynamic em C#?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação

Estava estudando C# e me deparei com um tipo de variável `dynamic`, que pelo que eu entendi, ela aceita qualquer valor que eu inserir. Do contrário de outras variáveis, como por exemplo:

Se eu declarar como `int`, eu tenho que digitar um `valor inteiro`.

Se eu declarar como `double`, eu tenho que digitar `valores quebrados`.

Eu não posso simplesmente declarar nome como `int` e atribuir `"Meu nome"` para a variável. Exemplo:

```
int nome = "Meu nome";
```

Porém, a variável `dynamic` tem uma dinâmica muito legal, como por exemplo:

```
dynamic nome = "Meu nome";
dynamic idade = 20;
```

> A minha dúvida é: Se em C# eu tenho uma variável que aceita qualquer
>   valor, em qual situação ela deve ser usada? E porque a linguagem não
>   usa apenas ela como tipo de variável já que ela aceita todos os valores?

Comment: Já lhe aconselho a tomar cuidado com o uso de `dynamic`, esse é um recurso poderoso que o `C#` possui (justamente por ser fortemente tipado), mas deve-se usar ele com cuidado. Ele tem casos bem específicos para ser usado, como `Dynamic Dispatch`, comunicação com `Views` (`ViewBag` do `ASP.NET MVC`), comunicação com outras tecnologias que não podem ser bem mapeadas no C# e/ou precisam de muita flexibilidade na mudança de contrato (`SignalR` com seus `Hubs`)...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Uma das características da linguagem C# é ser de [tipagem estática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_tipada), isso garante que cada tipo seja usado apenas onde ele é esperado.

O tipo [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/dd264736.aspx) foi criado para simplificar o acesso às COM APIs. Na maior parte das situações ele se comporta como o tipo *Object*.

Enquanto os outros tipos são verificados durante a compilação, o tipo *dynamic* só é verificado durante a execução.

A vantagem da verificação durante a compilação é o programador ser de imediato avisado dum possível mau uso do tipo.

Pode encontrar um lista completa das vantagens da tipagem estática nesta excelente [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/2541) dada na pergunta [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/2541).

Answer (score 18):

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa sobre o `dynamic` ele não torna as variáveis sem tipo, essa palavra-chave indica apenas que o compilador não deve verificar o seu tipo. C# é uma linguagem de tipagem estática (esse é o termo correto, também há bastante confusão sobre isso) e as variáveis só podem ter um tipo. O que pode acontecer é que a variável pode ter seu tipo trocado, e justamente por isso a verificação do compilador precisa ser desligada. Isso pode ser verificado com esse código:

```
dynamic x = 1;
WriteLine(x.GetType());
x = "oi";
WriteLine(x.GetType());
```

Veja [demonstração no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qxDtid). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/Type.cs).

> Se em C# eu tenho uma variável que aceita qualquer valor, em qual situação ela deve ser usada?

Ele foi criado para interoperabilidade com outras linguagens que possuem tipagem dinâmica e com APIs externas (por COM, por exemplo) que não tipam seus dados. Foi feito para uso com reflexão em alguns casos onde o dinamismo é importante. Um exemplo está na pergunta [Como criar propriedades dinamicamente em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101) ou [Pegar valores de uma lista dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105776/101). Tem uma [pergunta mostrando as diferentes formas de lidar quando não se sabe exatamente qual é o tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57333/101) e `dynamic` deve ser evitado.

De uma certa forma ela perde a segurança de tipos já que o compilador fica impedido de fazer alguma verificação. Varias coisas ficam *tricky* (complicado) de usar quando se abusa de `dynamic`. Isso já ocorre em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, mas as pessoas se acostumam. Quando mistura as duas coisas fica bem complicado. A maioria dos recursos do C# foi pensado para uso com tipagem estática, quando entra um tipo dinâmico algumas coisas podem não funcionar como se espera, ainda que os criadores da linguagem tenham feito um bom trabalho para mitigar a maioria dos casos que ficariam esquisitos.

> E por que a linguagem não usa apenas ela como tipo de variável já que ela aceita todos os valores?

É uma questão de filosofia da linguagem de mater a segurança de tipos. Quando começa usar isso passa ser sua responsabilidade garantir que o tipo esteja sempre correto. Ou por observação no código ou mesmo escrevendo código que garante isso. Se usar algo errado obterá uma exceção por erro de programação que o ideal é que nunca ocorra. Tem que estar muito mais o código.

## Alternativas

Já [o `var` foi criado para que o tipo possa ser inferido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101), ou seja, funciona normalmente como todo tipo, só que não precisa escrever o nome do tipo na declaração, o compilador descobre sozinho.

Também pode usar o tipo `object`, a variável deste tipo pode receber valores de qualquer tipo porque todos os tipos são descendentes de `object`. Só que você precisaria fazer *casting* para acessos os membros do tipo real do objeto. O compilador te protege de acessar membros que não sejam do tipo declarado. Se tentar acessar direto pelo tipo `object` só poderá acessar os [membros desse tipo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Não é o ideal. O `dynamic` tem a vantagem justamente por impedir o compilador de verificar se os membros estão disponíveis, ele aceita tudo.

## Linguagem adequada

Se acha que usar esse recurso é benéfico para uso generalizado na linguagem - muita gente não acha - então talvez C# não seja a melhor linguagem para você. Se quiser continuar no .NET seria melhor usar [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) (não é tão dinâmica assim) ou [IronPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) (pouco suportada), só para dar dois exemplos. Mas pra falar a verdade se quer algo dinâmico mesmo, acho melhor esquecer o .NET, dá para usá-lo, mas ele não foi pensado para usar desta forma.

Para usar C# precisa se identificar com a tipagem estática. Ela tem vantagens e desvantagens. Tem que escolher o que deseja. C# colocou essa facilidade para um objetivo específico, mas para mudar a filosofia da linguagem. Eu mesmo já pensei que poderia usá-la de uma forma mais dinâmica já que minha vida toda usei mais linguagens com tipagem dinâmica, mas percebi que seria um erro, ou faz como a linguagem foi projetada ou desiste dela.

Comment: Axo que faltou na minha resposta em tempo de compilacao, talvez :p. Removo até a resposta, nao vale a pena deixar a sua e a minha ao mesmo tempo, a sua está mais completa tb. +2

Comment: @BrunoCosta não tem porque apagar uma resposta a não ser que ela esteja errada. Toda informação é útil, mesmo como complemento. Uma outra visão, uma outra forma de expressar pode ajudar a pessoa entender melhor.

Comment: @bigown o mais legal é a inteligência que a linguagem tem, para distinguir os tipos dos valores que estão sendo atribuídos nas variáveis do tipo dynamic. Executei o exemplo que você colocou no dotNetFiddle, e achei bem bacana.

Comment: Isso é importante, os valores continuam tendo tipo fixo, a variável é que pode receber um objeto de tipo diferente nela e o compilador não fala nada, espera apenas que você saiba o que está fazendo.

Comment: @bigown show de bola sua explicação. E eu concordo com você, como disse, se você não se identifica com a linguagem é melhor mudar de linguagem, temos que conhecer a linguagem, aplicar boas práticas e trabalhar da forma que a linguagem foi projetada para poder ter bons resultados, no caso trabalhar da forma correta.

Comment: Eu me identifico com a linguagem, mas como estou iniciando na programação estou tentando entender melhor tudo o que preciso saber para que eu possa realmente escolher. Agora eu entendi melhor. rs