# Como passar e percorrer um objeto anônimo em um método

Tags: c#, .net, tipo-anônimo

Como eu posso passar um objeto anônimo para um método, e então percorrê-lo?

O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:

```
public static string QueryStringToUrl(string url, Dictionary<string, string> query)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

    // Aqui o objeto anônimo seria percorrido e então adicionaria
    // um novo parâmetro para a QueryString da URL AO INVÉS do dicionário.
    foreach (var q in query)
    {
        queryString[q.Key] = q.Value;
    }

    uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

E estou chamando assim:

```
QueryStringToUrl("http://example.com/?param1=abc", new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "param2", "12345" },
    { "otherParam", "huehue" }
});
// URL passada -> http://example.com/?param1=abc
// URL retorno -> http://example.com/?param1=abc&param2=12345&otherParam=huehue
```

Porém eu gostaria que fosse assim:

```
QueryStringToUrl("http://example.com/?param1=abc", new
{
    param2 = 12345,
    otherParam = "huehuehue"
});
// URL passada -> http://example.com/?param1=abc
// URL retorno -> http://example.com/?param1=abc&param2=12345&otherParam=huehue
```

> Exemplo de uso semelhante com **Jil** para serializar em JSON:

```
JSON.Serialize(new
{
    param2 = 12345,
    otherParam = "huehuehue"
})
```

**Saída:**

```
{"param2":"12345","otherParam":"huehuehue"}
```

[Jil no GitHub](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil):

Conheci o Jil [aqui](https://stackexchange.com/about/performance). No fim da página "**Programming Stack**"

Comment: É impossível, C# é uma linguagem com tipagem rígida. Se precisa mesmo desse tipo de coisa deveria seria melhor trabalhar com outra linguagem.

Comment: Explique o objetivo pra ver uma solução melhor.

Comment: kkkkkkkk, desculpa é que eu usava assim pra serializar em JSON com o Jil (Adicionei a pergunta), eu achei que o código ficava bonito e mais fácil de entender, ai achei que dava pra fazer isso também e que não tivesse problema =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível usando reflexão, mas não recomendo, economiza digitação, mas perder velocidade e pode criar dificuldades de manutenção. O Jil faz isso, mas de maneira mais performática.

Note que o exemplo onde foi usado tem um [método genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57333/101).

Eu prefiro usar `(param2 : 12345, otherParam : "huehuehue")`. Mas criar um tipo é melhor. Também deve funcionar com um tipo [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101), embora [raramente ele é necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101), mesmo que as pessoas acha que seja, mas o que deve ter melhor performance é o `Dictionary` mesmo.

O código a seguir funciona para todos.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => Teste(new { param2 = 12345, otherParam = "huehuehue" });
    public static void Teste<T>(T param){
        foreach (var item in typeof(T).GetProperties()) WriteLine($"{item.Name} : {item.GetValue(param, null)}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8Vl5RW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2HkQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/TraverseObject.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado :D, tava bem curioso kkkkkkk. Vou utilizar dicionário mesmo, gosto de performance, apesar que eu acredito que faço muita coisa nenhum pouco performática, achando que to fazendo kkkk .--.

Comment: Recomenda que eu utilize também um dicionário no Jil?

Comment: Não conheço a tecnologia o suficiente para opinar