# Por que não posso declarar um atributo usando a palavra-chave var?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, variáveis

A palavra-chave `var` permite que eu declare variáveis tipadas, e permite que as variáveis sejam definidas de forma implícita.

Exemplo: `var i = 10;`

O compilador vai presumir que minha variável `i` é do tipo inteiro `int`.

Sendo assim, porque o compilador não permite que eu use a palavra-chave `var` para declarações de atributos dentro de uma classe?

Veja este exemplo para ilustração:

```
class ClasseExemplo 
{
    public var atributo; //Este atributo poderia ser declarado de forma implícita.

    public ClasseExemplo() 
    {
        this.atributo = null;
    }
}
```

O exemplo acima retorna o seguinte erro:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Se desta forma eu não consigo declarar *um atributo que pode ser de qualquer tipo*, poderia haver outra forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A resposta simples: porque a especificação da linguagem diz que não deve inferir neste caso. Ou seja, os criadores da linguagem acharam que não valia a pena fazer isto. Há linguagens que inferem.

## Detalhando

Para conseguir isso o compilador ficaria bem mais complicado. Algumas situações são bem difíceis ou até impossíveis de inferir. Claro que poderia inferir até certo ponto e exigir o tipo em outros casos, mas preferiram não investir nisso (há propostas para fazê-lo), até porque alguns membros da classe fazem parte do contrato dela, nesse caso é melhor ser mais explícito, ainda que isto não me convença muito. O problema é o enorme trabalho para fazer certo.

De fato algumas situações poderiam tornar a compilação lenta e confusa. Existem casos de referências encadeadas e até mesmo cíclicas. Existem casos que para compilar aquilo primeiro precisa compilar outras unidades para garantir que está com o código mais atualizado, existem casos de inicialização estática onde a ordem pode não ser garantida.

A [resposta mais oficial pode ser obtida com um dos criadores do compilador](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-var-on-fields?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Pode ter ficado mais complicado com a possibilidade de inicializar a propriedade também desde o C# 6.

Usar [`var` não significa que pode usar qualquer tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101), significa apenas que não precisa digitar o tipo.

O que está sendo chamado de [atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). [Atributo é outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Hoje o C# tem a opção de utilização do tipo estático dynamic, que trabalharia da forma desejada, mais eu não vejo isso como uma boa pratica de programação, pois o objeto fica aberto a receber qualquer tipo de dados (inclusive objetos complexos) e a não utilização de um contrato pode causar problemas, por exemplo se o usuário chamar um método ou atributo não existente do objeto instanciado, o compilador permite a chamada e compila sem erros, porém na execução ele não encontra e lança uma exceção. Veja dynamic na documentação da Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Não parece que esta seja a forma deseja.

Comment: Sem falar que, como você setaria o tipo de retorno do método que retorna-se `atributo`? `Int`, `String`? Se fosse possível definir um atributo do tipo `var` na classe, automaticamente ele não poderia ter métodos que o retornassem.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Teria que ser `dynamic`. Mas na verdade o `dynamic` pode ser convertido para um tipo estático, claro que não seria mais o campo da classe.

Comment: @bigown Exatamente, por isso que não teria logica usar `var` em uma classe.

Answer (score 5):

Veja, como já foi dito na resposta do @Maniero

> Usar var não significa que pode usar qualquer tipo, significa apenas que não precisa digitar o tipo.

Em termos mais simples isso quer dizer que é o compilador que escolhe o tipo da variável por você. Ai você pode perguntar: "Mas como ele faz isso?"

Ele faz isso analisando o que há do lado direito da declaração. Exemplo:

```
var i = 10;
```

**10** é número inteiro, logo, a variável `i` será do tipo `int`. Se na sequência eu tentar fazer

```
i = "qualquer coisa";
```

vou receber o erro

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

---

> **Se desta forma eu não consigo declarar um atributo que pode ser de qualquer tipo, poderia haver outra forma de fazer isto?**

**Sim**, você pode usar [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx) para isso. `Dynamic` te dá a liberdade de fazer o que queres - uma propriedade que pode ter seu tipo mudado a qualquer momento. Veja um exemplo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    dynamic i = 10;

    WriteLine(i.GetType()); //output: System.Int32

    i = "teste";

    WriteLine(i.GetType()); //output: System.String
}
```

Tenha em mente que isso pode (e que vai) dar algum problema caso você não tenha certeza do que está fazendo. Talvez, com mais detalhes, nós possamos te ajudar melhor com isso, mas só com o que disse fica difícil.

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro problema é que as variáveis de tipo implícito tem que ser imediatamente inicializadas(e não vale = **null**).

É como o @Maniero disse  `Usar var não significa que pode usar qualquer tipo, significa apenas que não precisa digitar o tipo.`

Se no escopo de um método você tem `var atributo = 5; atributo = "string";` imediatamente vai receber um erro de **compilação** e não de **execução**!

Mas mesmo que você fizesse

```
class ClasseExemplo 
{
    public var atributo = 5;

}
```

Não é possível declarar variáveis de classe com tipo implícito .

Ele funciona assim :

Primeiro faz um mapeamento de todas as classes , atributos de classe , declarações de método... pra depois fazer a análise do escopo dos métodos e é  na análise de escopo dos métodos , com base no que ele já sabe da primeira etapa que ocorre a inferência do tipo para o var. Ou seja , pra que isso funcione teriam de reescrever o método de compilação. ( o que poderiam implementar , mas optaram por não fazer).

Uma opnião sobre a questão abordada no [artigo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/) , que em um dos tópicos fala a respeito da dificuldade do compilador tratar vars referenciando outros tipos implícitos em cadeia é que eles poderiam especificar que um var não pode referenciar outro tipo implícito em atributos de classe.

A limitação provavelmente é por falta de interesse .