# Existe uma funcionalidade em C# similar ao __call do PHP?

Tags: c#, .net, métodos-mágicos

Tenho muita experiência com PHP e, como estou começando agora com C#, vai ser comum eu querer comparar uma linguagem com outra para descobrir se posso fazer algo similar.

Em PHP, eu posso adicionar uma funcionalidade à uma classe para que, quando o método não existe, uma ação seja executada. É o método mágico `__call`. Ou seja, ele adiciona uma chamada dinâmica para métodos que não foram definidos na classe baseado naquilo que é definido em `__call`.

De acordo com o Manual:

> **__call()** é disparado ao invocar métodos inacessíveis em um contexto de objeto.

Por exemplo,

```
 class Dynamic {

        public function action() {
           return 'existe';
        }

        public function __call($method, $parameters) {
              return "Não existe, mas farei alguma coisa com {$method}";
        }
 }


 $d = new Dynamic();

 $d->action(); // 'existe'

 $d->naoExisteEsseMetodo(); // 'Não existe, mas farei alguma coisa com naoExisteEsseMethodo'
```

Observe que o último método chamado não existe, mas "algo é feito" mesmo assim.

Existe alguma maneira de criar funcionalidade similar ao `__call` do PHP em C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você está procurando pela classe [`DynamicObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e outras do *namespace* [`System.Dynamic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), além da própria palavra chave [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101) que manda o compilador não verificar possíveis erros no acesso a membros deste objeto deixando para o tempo de execução resolver isto ou emitir erro.

Uma das ações possíveis desta classe é executar algum método na ausência do método chamado, isto é feito com o [`TryInvokeMember()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Dynamic_DynamicObject_TryInvokeMember_System_Dynamic_InvokeMemberBinder_System_Object___System_Object__).

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
 
class Dinamica : DynamicObject {
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result) {
        result = null;
        Console.WriteLine($"Executando método \"{binder.Name}\".");
        return true;
    }
}
 
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic din = new Dinamica();
        din.NaoExiste();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Bf3Yq1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BdjmVW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/Call.cs).

Se quiser fazer uma classe mais sofisticada:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

public class Dynamic : DynamicObject {
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) => dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result) {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name)) {
            ((Action)dictionary[binder.Name]).Invoke(); //fiz gambi, precisa elaborar mais esta chamada para adequadar para qualquer tipo
            result = "Método dinâmico executou";
            return true;
        }
        try {
            result = (typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)).InvokeMember(binder.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, dictionary, args);
        } catch {
            result = "Resultado falho";
            WriteLine($"Executando método \"{binder.Name}\".");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Print() {
        foreach (var pair in dictionary) {
            if (!(pair.Value is Delegate)) WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
        }
        if (dictionary.Count == 0) WriteLine("Sem membros para listar");
    }
}
```

O uso:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic din = new Dynamic(); //precisa ser dynamic para o compilador não reclamar dos membros dinâmicos
        din.Nome = "Walla"; //criando membros dinamicamente
        din.Sobrenome = "C#";
        din.Action = new Action(() => WriteLine("Action Existe")); //isto não era necessário
        din.Print(); //chama um método existente na classe
        din.Action(); //chama o método que acabou de ser criado
        din.Clear(); //chama um método disponível no dicionário interno, mas que não está definido na classe
        din.Print(); //tá limpo
        din.NaoExiste(); //este método não existe
        dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject();
        exp.Action = new Action(() => WriteLine("Expando")); //só para mostrar que é possível fazer de forma automática, mas precisaria pesquisar
        exp.Action();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/umqqsr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iDEYDS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/Call2.cs).

## Algumas considerações

Uma classe assim é tão flexível que você pode fazer uma e usar para qualquer coisa.

Em condições de produção muitas melhorias seriam necessárias neste código.

Um exemplo de gambiarra: eu fiz um *cast* para o tipo `Action` que em condições normais eu não poderia saber qual é o tipo em tempo de compilação. Para fazer a chamada do jeito correto para qualquer assinatura de método teria que produzir uma infraestrutura semelhante ao que a classe [`ExpandoObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) fez. Tanto que eu até a uso pra mostrar que criar métodos dinâmicos é algo possível. A `ExpandoObject` é uma classe dinâmica pronta para uso, mas ela não é tão flexível.

O exemplo permite criar e acessar propriedades e métodos existentes na classe, em outra classe, criados na instância e execução padrão (*fallback*) que é o foco da pergunta.

## Dinamismo

Dá para notar que esta classe coloca uma capa em cima de um dicionário para armazenar os membros. Há quem prefira ser explícito e usar esta estrutura de dados bruta para guardar os dados. Faz algum sentido se não gostar de açúcar sintático.

Concluímos que C# tem diversas vantagens sobre o PHP e as desvantagens são minimizadas. Não é recomendável, mas se quiser pode fazer um sistema todo e até mais flexível que o PHP.

Este é um recurso que deve ser evitado, mas onde ele é útil pode ser usado igual ou melhor que no PHP, isto vale para manipulação de arquivos externos diverso (CSV, JSON, XML, etc.), integração com outras linguagens dinâmicas ou produtos que usam dinamismo (muita coisa da Microsoft é assim) e pode deixar um sistema extremamente configurável e flexível, se souber o que está fazendo. Em alguns tipos de produto isto é fundamental. Alias se os programadores soubessem usar recursos deste tipo melhor poderia eliminar muito trabalho repetitivo que nem percebem.

Lembrando que o uso de dinamismo exige muito mais atenção por parte do programador, e verificações extras no código são necessárias. A performance deixa a desejar nestes casos (não use onde ela é importante).

Comment: Até hoje eu nunca tive que usar em produção o DynamicObject, só precisei usar o dynamic somente para uns dois casos, me lembro que um deles foi para importação de dados de um TXT. Um caso que eu acho bastante útil esse dinamismo do C# como exemplo são os Hubs do SignalR, que servem para mapear chamadas de funções do JS. Acho uma solução elegante, em vez de precisar definir interfaces para isso, como é feito em outros frameworks.

Comment: Sobre os Hubs do SignalR:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Comment: Esse é um bom exemplo de como se deve usar desse dinamismo que o C# nos permite elaborar no nosso código.

Comment: Isto foi um adendo apenas? Tomei negativo na resposta agora, fiquei pensando se achou algo errado nela. Não que tenha sido seu. É que queria saber o que tem de erro aqui. Vale para quem negativou.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pode ser pela gambiarra. Aí vamos esperar a pessoa colocar a solução correta. Só fiz porque era uma informação útil e não afeta o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Foi um adendo, não negativei. Concordo com o que foi dito.

Comment: Quem negativou tava querendo te botar pra baixo, pois não há gambiarra nesta solução. Uma gamb ferrada seria emitir código IL manualmente afim de gerar uma classe em tempo de execução e depois chamar via reflexão... isso sim é gambiarra... =D

Answer (score 8):

#### Não tente comparar C# com PHP!

Não digo isso por maldade, e sim pois são linguagens diferentes com suas particularidades. O C# é extremamente tipado, ou seja, não é possível fazer algo desse nível naturalmente. Porém, na versão 4.0 do C#, foi introduzido o [tipo dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), onde você consegue fazer algo "parecido".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
    
    dynamic dynamic_ec = new ExampleClass();
   
    dynamic_ec.exampleMethod1(10, 4);
     // As seguintes chamadas não causam erros do compilador, se 
    // existe ou não métodos apropriados. 
    dynamic_ec.someMethod("some argument", 7, null);
    dynamic_ec.nonexistentMethod();
}

class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClass() { }
    public ExampleClass(int v) { }

    public void exampleMethod1(int i) { }

    public void exampleMethod2(string str) { }
}
```

Outra forma também é utilizar reflections, como falado na [resposta do @jbueno.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137545/20615), algo parecido com isso:

```
ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
Type type = ec .GetType();
MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("nonexistentMethod");
m.Invoke(ec , new object[] {});
```

Porém, vale ressaltar que **eu** não vejo necessidade na utilização de algo parecido com isso, não no contexto da pergunta.

Referências:

- [# Equivalent of PHP Dynamic Method Calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899814/c-sharp-equivalent-of-php-dynamic-method-calling)
- [Using Type dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: Botei este código pra testar e não consegui mesmo consertando algumas coisas. Você sabe se tem que mexer mais alguma coisa? https://dotnetfiddle.net/gFGSCl

Comment: @bigown No seu exemplo, o ideone não consegue acessar a classe, basta colocar como public que terá o resultado mostrado no site da MS, ou seja, uma mensagem de erro falando que o método não existe. Segundo o tutorial, essa forma é para não dar erros na compilação, ou seja, no build. Traduzi a parte dos comentários que dizia isso e adicionei à resposta. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: Verdade, aí muda o erro. O que você quis dizer é que o erro muda do tempo de compilação pra tempo de execução então?

Comment: @bigown Sim. Não tem tratamento para executar qualquer coisa caso não ache o método, e como a resposta do jbueno já tinha isso, achei desnecessário adicionar.

Answer (score 6):

Até onde eu sei, não existe. Pelo simples fato de que C# é completamente diferente de PHP.

Se você tentar chamar um método que não existe em C#, a aplicação não vai compilar e pronto. Não é necessária nenhuma estratégia para caso tente chamar um método que não existe. Claro que você pode *"tentar"* chamar um método que não existe usando *reflection*, aí seria necessário implementar alguma estratégia para executar alguma coisa quando o método não existir.

Exemplo, se você tentar algo como `obj.GetType().GetMethod("MetodoInexistente").Invoke(a, new object[0])` receberá uma **`NullReferenceException`**.

Vide [esta resposta no StackOverflow, para uma pergunta similar a sua.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841339/4190610) Nesse caso, é usado `obj.CallOrDefault("MetodoInexistente", arg1, arg2);`

```
public static class PhpStyleDynamicMethod
{
    public static void __call(Type @class, object[] parameters)
    {
        // Aqui vai a implementação do "__call"
    }

    public static object CallOrDefault(this object b, string method, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var methods = b.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == method && DoParametersMatch(m.GetParameters(), parameters));

        var count = methods.Count();

        if (count == 1)
            return methods.Single().Invoke(b, parameters);

        if (count > 1)
            throw new ApplicationException("could not resolve a single method.");

        __call(b.GetType(), parameters);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade, a funcionalidade não é só para "ter uma estratégia para um método que não existe". Em linguagens dinamicas como php e python é comum, para criar funcionalidades, como, por exemplo, o pattern Fluent, onde eu poderia chamar os métodos assim: `a.b().c().d().e().f()` entre outras coisas que poderia fazer usando a criatividade.

Comment: Ainda não entendi a necessidade. Em linguagens estaticamente tipadas como C#, você pode fazer `a.b().c().d().e().f()`. Desde que, o **tipo retornado** no método `b()` tenha o método `c()` e assim por diante.

Comment: É só um exemplo. Eu posso por exemplo usar o `__call` e verificar se o `$method` inicia com `set` ou `get` e criar uma regra dinâmica para definição de atributos da classe (como  `setNome`, `setIdade`, sem esses existirem)

Comment: Essas "mágicas" é coisa de linguagem dinâmica, né?

Comment: Eu não sou a melhor pessoa pra afirmar algo, mas acho que sim.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters C# é tão boa que se você quiser fazer ela ficar dinâmica, pode. Não é recomendável, mas nos casos onde isto é útil, pode usar pontualmente como se fosse PHP. Claro que tem soluções que não serão tão convenientes. Vou melhorar minha resposta nesse sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Bom ... uma das diferenças básicas entre o C# e o PHP é que C# é uma linguagem TIPADA, ou seja os tipos são conhecidos com suas características (métodos e propriedades), já PHP é uma linguagem não tipada, por isso tem um método genérico que quando chamado algo que não existe este é invocado.

A parte boa de ser tipado, é que ajuda e muito a ferramenta de desenvolvimento a te ajudar, já que o intellisense (sugestão de comando ao iniciar digitar) já pode prever o que tem aquele objeto, inclusive com os métodos extendidos o qual tu próprio pode criar e estender um método para uma classe de sistema!

Então... não vejo o porque C# ter algo parecido com o "_CALL" uma vez que que for utilizar o projeto saberá todas as características disponíveis, inclusive se este for uma DLL referenciada ao seu projeto.

Seja bem-vindo ao mundo .NET!