# Por que o uso de dynamic é algo a ser evitado?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem

Minha empresa trabalha com desenvolvimento, é uma pratica da empresa que todos os códigos feitos sejam revisados por outra pessoa antes de serem aprovados em *pull request*.

Geralmente meus códigos possuem somente alguns detalhes a serem alterados, porém dessa ultima vez o revisor comentou em um trecho de código onde eu usava `dynamic` para atribuir o tipo do retorno no método alegando que isso é uma prática ruim e não aceitaria aquele PR por isso.

No exemplo específico era em um método que podia receber tanto números quanto *strings*, concatenando o resultado em casos de *string* ou somando em casos de números, então a saída tinha tipo que dependia do tipo de entrada.

Então fiquei com 3 dúvidas:

- Porque o uso de `dynamic` é considerado uma prática a ser evitada?
- Existe algo que possa substituir o uso com o mesmo efeito?
- Qual caso onde o uso de `dynamic` é necessário?

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença entre object, dynamic e var](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/18246)

Comment: Qual foi o uso do dynamic no seu codigo?

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que os outros tipos de variáveis não são substituídos por dynamic em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161729/18246)

Comment: @LeoLonghi era em um método que podia receber tanto numeros quanto strings, concatenando o resultado em casos de string ou somando em casos de numeros, então a saída devia ser algo que era mutável.

Comment: @Paz este seu método já me parece uma `anti-pattern`

Comment: @TobiasMesquita não sei o que é um anti-pattern, irei procurar

Comment: interessante, não conheço c#, mas depois de olhar as resposta abaixo, chego a conclusão que o dynamics é comparável com uma feature do javascript onde você pode fazer um objeto sem propriedades (var a = {}) e atribuir propriedades em tempo de execução fazendo a.propriedade ou a['propriedade']. Do ponto de vista orientado à objeto, isso é ruim, pois estamos assumindo que um objeto não é tipado e isso meio que força um outro programador a ter que ler um trecho de código inteiro para tentar entender a definição de um objeto (e ainda está suscetível a entender errado).

Comment: @Paz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189442/101 tentei responder da forma mais completa possível, mas sei lá porque as pessoas não estão enxergando isso. tem alço que você vê de errado ou faltando na minha reposta?

Comment: @bigown é muito mais completa que as respostas que achei pela web, na verdade me parece um compilado de tudo que achei, realmente excepcional. +1

Comment: @wryel 1) A sua comparação com o Javascript está equivocada e seria mais comparável com tipos "anônimos". O JS tem tipagem dinâmica, a comparação correta seria com as variáveis e comportamento dos objetos. 2) O objeto é tipado como `dynamic`, o valor do objeto que tem tipos diferentes.

Comment: 3) O código de um programa deve ser escrito com legibilidade, mas favorecer o programador (e sua provável incompetência) em detrimento da qualidade/resultado programa (o resultado do código) é um erro grave! O programa deve ser entendível para facilitar a manutenção daqueles capacitados para tal. Se a funcionalidade foi introduzido, é porque ele foi necessária para determinados objetivos.

Comment: Imagine deserializar um JSON polimórfico sem dynamic.

Comment: @Edney mas aí não poderiamos usar um object anônimo?

Comment: Também, normalmente essa restrição é uma questão administrativa, a tipagem forte garante que não haverá erro de tipo, desde o código. Em produção é indesejável depender de dynamic, mas para depuração e desenvolvimento (quando se tem um ambiente mais controlado) é um recurso bem útil. Sem contar que o dynamic gera um processamento a mais de resolução de tipo. Tive professores que condenavam o uso de goto, muitos veem goto e já dizem que é spaghetti code, em c# é difícil fazer recursão de cauda sem goto, é mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nunca aceite algo que diz que uma prática é boa ou ruim, isso serve pra nada a não ser para a pessoa que disse "impor" a sua vontade. Se a pessoa explicar o porquê daquilo deixa de ser uma mera prática e passa ser uma informação relevante para você tomar melhores decisões.

> Porque o uso de *dynamic* é considerado uma prática a ser evitada?

Não é uma prática ruim, deve ser usado onde ele é necessário. Não deve ser usado onde existe outra solução melhor, como todos mecanismos da linguagem.

`dynamic` basicamente desliga a verificação de tipos e é problema seu acessar membros existentes no objeto, se é isso que precisa, use-o.

[Leitura complementar importante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). E [também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

> Existe algo que possa substituir o uso com o mesmo efeito?

Depende do que precisa. Efeito idêntico não.

- Tem casos que pode ser usado um [`object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) no lugar, generaliza o tipo, mas não desliga a verificação de tipo, então só pode acessar os membros de `object`, mesmo que o objeto tenha outros membros. Se quiser acessar esses membros deve fazer um `cast`. Pouco interessante na maioria dos casos, mas útil em alguns raros.
- Pode usar [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) (conceito). A maior parte do que você pensar em `dynamic` pode ser mais bem resolvido com esse mecanismo de forma muito melhor.
- Se a única coisa que deseja é não digitar o tipo do dado então é só usar o [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101).
- Usar um [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), a sintaxe pode não ser a mais agradável, mas essencialmente é a mesma semântica que o `dynamic` dá e em vários casos fica mais claro o que está fazendo.
- **Provável solução para seu caso**: Se é um parâmetro de um método que pode trabalhar com tipos não relacionados você deve usar [*overloading*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101) e ter métodos diferentes para operações diferentes.

  Pelos comentários parece ser o caso. Se for o retorno, como não existe sobrecarga neste caso tem que criar um método com um nome diferente. Se retorna tipos diferentes significa que os métodos são diferentes. Se tem `if` dentro do método para decidir o que fazer, certamente a solução é criar uma sobrecarga do método.
- Se na verdade apenas quer poder receber objetos da mesma hierarquia pode ser útil apenas usar [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158579/101).
- Existem soluções mais malucas que nem vou referir.

[Códigos mostrando isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57333/101).

> Onde o uso de dynamic é necessário?

Sempre que você não tem controle sobre a estrutura do objeto.

Ele foi criado principalmente para interoperabilidade com aplicações e códigos externos, como [COM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198929/101) e outras linguagens "dinâmicas" que rodam no [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

Ou é usado para objetos que precisam ser estruturados (não só criados) em tempo de execução, por exemplo criar uma classe baseada em uma tabela de um banco de dados que você desconhece ([exemplo prático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105776/101)). Outro exemplo comum é receber um JSON que você não sabe como virá ([exemplo prático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101)). Mas se você sabe a estrutura então não tem por que usar.

[Outro exemplo prático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137542/101).

Não tem a ver com gosto, tem a ver com necessidade. Em uma linguagem estática não é idiomático deixar a tipagem dinâmica. Abusar de `dynamic` é algo considerado ruim em C#. Usar onde é a melhor solução não tem problema.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: "Nunca aceite algo que diz que uma prática é boa ou ruim, isso não serve pra nada a não ser para a pessoa "impor" a sua vontade. Se a pessoa explicar o porquê daquilo deixa de ser uma mera prática e passa ser uma informação relevante para você tomar melhores decisões." Já vi muito, muito desenvolvedor falar sobre "nuncas" e "evites" sem saber o porquê além de "porque é má prática". São os famosos papagaios de pirata.

Answer (score 19):

Basicamente, ele não deve ser evitado. Você tem saber **como** usar e **quando** usar. Essa história de ser "boa prática" ou "má prática" é, majoritariamente, um artifício usado pra impor regras sem precisar embasar o que está falando.

> Porque o uso de `dynamic` é considerado uma prática a ser evitada?

Só quem te disse isso pode responder esta pergunta. Mas é bem provável que seja porque, usando `dynamic`, tudo é resolvido em tempo de execução e não compilação, dessa forma é muito mais fácil fazer alguma besteira e acabar quebrando a execução da aplicação.

Trocando em miúdos, você simplesmente "joga fora" uma das grandes vantagens de linguagens estáticas que é justamente conhecer de antemão todos os (possíveis) membros existentes de um objeto.

Um pequeno exemplo:

```
dynamic pessoa = new { Nome = "jbueno" };
var n = pessoa.nome;
```

Este código compila normalmente, porém estoura um erro em tempo de execução porque a propriedade `nome` não existe em `pessoa`.

> Existe algo que possa substituir o uso com o mesmo efeito?

Se por "efeito" você se refere à dinamicidade: a resposta é não. E se isto for realmente necessário eu até te diria que provavelmente você esteja usando a linguagem errada.

Pra outros casos é possível te dar algumas dicas conhecendo a real necessidade. Citar todas as possibilidades é inviável.

> Qual caso onde o uso de `dynamic` é necessário?

Depende um pouco. Ele é necessário sempre que você não puder saber de antemão a estrutura do objeto.

Um exemplo real seria fazer uma requisição para um *webservice* cujo retorno possa ter duas estruturas completamente diferentes.

Muito provável que existam outros casos em que ele seja mais útil. Acho difícil que a criação deste recurso tenha sido pra resolver casos como este do exemplo.

> ```
> { "sucesso": "true" };
> { "erro": "Algo deu errado" };
> ```

Comment: Tem como explicar o motivo do _downvote_ pra eu poder arrumar a resposta?

Comment: O autor do noto negativo poderia esclarecer o motivo?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Acho que foi sem motivo mesmo. De qualquer forma, tentei revisar a resposta e não achei nada errado. Se você encontrar algo pode me avisar.

Comment: os teus exemplos seriam apropriados para o uso de "anonymous", já que são objetos não-nomeados.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Não entendi. O que você quer dizer com "anonymous"? Tipos anônimos só podem ser criados em tempo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, `dynamic pessoa = new { Nome = "jbueno" };` não seria um bom uso pelo teu já citado erro de compilação, que seria pego se fosse definido como `var pessoa = ...`, já que até onde o exemplo vai, você não precisa dele como `dynamic` para interoperabilidade.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58529/discussion-between-andre-figueiredo-and-jbueno).

Comment: Gostaria de registrar que sua resposta foi extraordinária, porém a resposta do usuário bigown foi escolhida como correta por incluir a solução para meu caso também. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Tranquilo. Eu não tentei solucionar seu problema porque não sei qual é.

Answer (score 8):

Perguntar por que uma funcionalidade é algo a ser evitado é como perguntar por que o uso de uma ferramenta deve ser evitada. E você nunca vai ouvir ninguém perguntando algo como "por que eu devo evitar utilizar chave-estrela".

O uso de uma funcionalidade só é uma má prática quando ela é utilizada como a solução certa para o problema errado, e vice-versa.

No seu caso, me parece pelos comentários que você quer utilizar o `dynamic` para variar o formato de retorno de um método, de acordo com o input. Isso é má prática porque:

- garante que a cada novo tipo de retorno que você tiver que tratar, aumenta a complexidade do código e de sua análise;
- C# é uma linguagem fortemente tipada - mas ao utilizar `dynamic` como você se propõe, você cria um ponto no sistema na qual a determinação de um tipo fica difícil.

Converse com o seu revisor e procure entender a visão dele, pois ele pode ainda ter um entendimento diferente do entendimento de cada pessoa que responder aqui.

Answer (score 7):

Mais uma percepção diferente.

Por sua natureza o `dynamic` pode ser usado para propósitos diferentes do seu objetivo. Assim é má prática utilizá-lo quando há claramente uma melhor alternativa disponível. E o que é "melhor alternativa"? É aí que surge o proibição "é má prática utilizá-lo".

Mas porque o `dynamic` existe então? É "mais uma" mancada da equipe do .NET?

A resposta começa a se desenhar uma vez que se sabe que o tipo `dynamic` foi introduzido no pacote de atualizações do .NET 4.0. Mais precisamente, como parte do Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR).

Bom, então ele foi introduzido numa versão tardia do .NET, logo não é algo legado. Definitivamente para suprir algo. Aqui entra a velha presunção de que devemos ter bons argumentos para entrar numa briga de grandes.

O tipo `dynamic` supre a falta/dificuldade de interoperabilidade do .NET  e simplifica códigos complexos, entre eles:

- Interoperabilidade com implementações de diversas linguagens dinâmicas em .NET (Iron), tal como IronRuby, IronPython and IronScheme, embora estejam abandonadas ou desatualizadas no presente momento;
- [Interoperabilidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop) com objetos [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), como omitir várias conversões de tipos e passagem de parâmetros vazios (*MissingValue*) - ex.: bibliotecas do Office;
- Manipulação de Tipos Complexos sem precisar criar diversas classes personalizadas, como XML e JSON. Ex.:

  ```
  public getFullName(String json){
      dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);

      return String.Join(" ", new string[] {
          data.results.info.name.first, data.results.info.name.last
      });
  }
  ```
- Alternativa ao uso de `Reflections` complexos.
- Como retorno ou parâmetros de funções, **onde não se aplica polimorfismo**.

---

Mas é bom notar que ele deve sim ser **evitado** em vários casos, sendo os mais comuns:

- meio de fuga de conversões entre tipos de dados;
- meio de fuga de conversões de/para classes reutilizáveis ou pertinentes a lógica de negócio;
- alternativa a polimorfismos, principalmente para unificar métodos com sobrecargas;
- alternativa a variáveis de tipo estático, fortemente tipadas, resolvidas em tempo de compilação, mas não de tipo implícito ou tipos não-nomeados, i.e., tudo que não é declarado como `<tipo> <nome_var>;`, principalmente substituindo tipos anônimos (`var a = {"b": 1};` -> `dynamic a = {"b": 1}`).