# Como posso editar um elemento desse array?

Tags: c#, array, lista

Eu tenho um array desse jeito:

```
List<dynamic> business_list = new List<dynamic>();

business_list.Add(new {
    business_Name = reader.GetString("name"),
    business_OwnerID = reader.GetInt32("owner_id")
});
```

---

```
List business_list = new List(); 

business_list.Add(new {
    business_Name = reader.GetString("name"), 
    business_OwnerID = reader.GetInt32("owner_id")
});
```

Como posso editar o elemento `business_Name`? Alguém pode me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você deveria usar uma lista genérica. As coleções não genéricas estão obsoletas.

Segundo, não é possível editar objetos de tipos anônimos, eles servem apenas para leitura. Ou seja, se você quer editar alguma propriedade é melhor criar uma classe.

```
public class Business
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Aí você pode criar a lista desta forma

```
var list = new List<Business>();
list.add(new Business 
         { 
             Name = reader.getString("name"), 
             OwnerId = reader.getString("owner_id") 
          });
```

A partir de então, vai poder acessar a lista pelos índices

```
var business = list[0];
business.Name = "Novo Nome";
```

Iterando os elementos

```
foreach(var business in list) 
{  
    business.Name = "Novo Nome";
}
```

Ou até mesmo usando LINQ

```
var business = list.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "Nome Antigo");
business.Name = "Novo Nome";
```

Sobre a lista dinâmica: eu não entendi muito bem porque você pôs ela solta na pergunta, mas aconselho dar uma lida [nas respostas desta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/203659/18246)

Comment: Estou pelo celular então fica meio difícil de escrever código. Qualquer coisa, só comentar que eu arrumo quando tiver acesso a um computador.