# Como acessar propriedades com "." no nome em um objeto dynamic

Tags: c#, json, desserialização

Tenho o seguinte objeto JSON:

```
{
    "odata.metadata":"httpXXXXX",
    "odata.count":1443,
    "value":[
    { "codigo" : 1 , "nome" : "ABS"}
    ]
}
```

e crio um objeto assim:

```
dynamic categorias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
```

Eu consigo acessar a propriedade `value` normalmente mas como faço para acessar a propriedade `odata.count` ?

PS.: Já estou utilizando a biblioteca Newtonsoft para manipular o json.

Grato.

Comment: Bah, você precisa mesmo usar `dynamic`?

Comment: Como não tenho controle do JSON que esta sendo gerado, entendo que sim. Mesmo se fosse criar uma classe, o que faço com essas propriedades com "."  no meio do nome?

Comment: Se fosse criar uma classe pra representar, você iria definir um nome sem ponto pra classe e fazer um mapeamento com o nome original.

Comment: Você não tem controle do JSON que está sendo gerado, mas sabe quais as propriedades que quer acessar, não sabe?

Comment: Hum, captei a ideia. Acho que posso resolver no mapeamento.

Comment: Deixei um exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como propriedade você não vai poder acessá-lo, o C# não tem nenhum mecanismo pra tratar disso.

De qualquer forma, um objeto `dynamic` nada mais é que um conjunto de chaves-valores, então, você pode acessar um valor por sua chave, desta maneira

Lembrando que isso pode não ser uma boa ideia.

```
var metadata = categorias["odata.metadata"];
```

Leitura indicada:

- [Por que o uso de dynamic é algo a ser evitado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/203659/18246)

---

Mesmo não tendo controle sobre o *payload* que será devolvido, você sempre terá que saber quais as propriedades que quer acessar. Isso é suficiente para criar uma classe de contrato para deserializar o JSON.

Veja como ficaria:

```
class RetornoWebservice
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "odata.metadata")]
    public string Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "odata.count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public IEnumerable<Valor> Valores { get; set; }
}

class Valor
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "codigo")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

E o uso seria algo como

```
var categorias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoWebservice>(jsonResult);

var metadata = categorias.Metadata;
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito Obrigado!