# Definir uma variável genérica sem definir o tipo

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, genéricos, declaração-de-variável

Eu estou fazendo alguns testes no Unity para eu praticar programação. Eu sou novato e essa pergunta pode ser meio idiota. Eu quero saber se isso é possível:

Eu criei a seguinte classe abstrata:

```
public abstract class Variable<T> : ScriptableObject {}
```

E quero usar essa classe como uma variável que irá aceitar filhos da tal classe:

```
private Variable<Int> variable;
```

Porém eu quero que a variável aceite filhos de qualquer tipo e não apenas do declarado  algo tipo:

```
private Variable variable;
```

Isso é possível?

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar `var`?

Comment: No unity só aceita c# 2.0 não dá para usar var :/

Comment: @ValterLuiz sugiro que você [leia aqui](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) e também assista o video sobre `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: @ValterLuiz Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Então você não quer usar *generics*. Esse mecanismo é para ter um tipo específico.

Em algum caso poderia usar um `object` que é o tipo de todos os tipos. Eu evitaria isso, quase nunca é adequando e provavelmente está fazendo uma escolha ruim de como arquitetar sua aplicação.

Pode ser ainda que precise mudar o tipo em tempo de execução, aí deveria usar [`dynamic`, mas eu evitaria mais ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101).

Se não souber usar muito bem esses mecanismos a aplicação se tornará instável.

Seria bom entender sobre [tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Me parece que esta herança também está errada, mas não posso afirmar só com o que tem na pergunta.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes aqui e o object ajudou, só não parece funcional. Eu já tinha dado uma olhada sobre o dynamic e sim tentei evitar.

O que eu tava tentando fazer é bem simples eu tenho duas classes:

`public class FloatVariable : ScriptableObject
{
 private float value;

 public void AddValue(float amount)
 {
  value += amount;
 }

}`

E outra que é basicamente a mesma coisa só que estruturada em Int

Eu estava tentando de alguma forma fazer a herança pois eu vi a mesma base que poderia ser aproveitada. :)

Comment: Eu poderia tentar ajudar mais, mas a pergunta não tem informações suficientes, do jeito que está não precisa de nada dessas coisas, mas sei lá, pode ser porque a descrição do problema ruim.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, nesse caso, você pode usar herança, com um superclass ou uma interface, e conforme você for identificando as necessidades em comum, você vai atribuindo a interface/SuperClass.

Acho que pode ajudar, outra opção, é o object mesmo, pois ele é o base dos tipos.

Espero ter ajudado, se falei bobeira me desculpe!