# Como funciona o método Type.InvokeMember()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

Me deparei com este método em um código e fiquei curioso em como acontece o funcionamento dele pois já vi algumas aplicações rodando em C# que utilizam este método, e ao procurar sobre o método no Google, não encontrei nenhuma explicação clara.

```
tipoServico.InvokeMember("SalvarXmlRetornoEm", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, xml, new object[] { repositorio.xmlRetorno });
```

Este é um exemplo de um código que eu vi que ele funciona tudo certinho mas que não faço ideia de como funciona rsrs.

```
 private void EnviarArquivo(Empresa empresa, string arquivoXmlEnvio, string localSalvarXmlRetorno, Object nfe, string metodo)
    {
        //Definir o tipo do serviço
        Type tipoServico = nfe.GetType();

        //Definir o arquivo XML para a classe UniNfeClass
        tipoServico.InvokeMember("NomeArquivoXML", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, nfe, new object[] { arquivoXmlEnvio });
        tipoServico.InvokeMember("SalvarXmlRetornoEm", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, nfe, new object[] { localSalvarXmlRetorno });
        tipoServico.InvokeMember(metodo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, nfe, new[] { empresa });
    }
```

Então o objeto NFe é este aqui:

```
public class TaskConsultarNfsePorRps : TaskAbst
{
    public override void Execute(Empresa empresa)
    {
        //Definir o serviço que será executado para a classe
        Servico = Servicos.ConsultarNfsePorRps;

        //Ler o XML para pegar parâmetros de envio
        LerXML ler = new LerXML();
        ler.PedSitNfseRps(NomeArquivoXML, empresa);

        //Criar objetos das classes dos serviços dos webservices do SEFAZ
        WebServiceProxy wsProxy = null;
        object pedLoteRps = null;
        string cabecMsg = "";
        PadroesNFSe padraoNFSe = Functions.PadraoNFSe(ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio);
        switch (padraoNFSe)
        {
            case PadroesNFSe.GINFES:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                cabecMsg = "<ns2:cabecalho versao=\"3\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.ginfes.com.br/cabecalho_v03.xsd\"><versaoDados>3</versaoDados></ns2:cabecalho>";
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.BETHA:
                wsProxy = new WebServiceProxy(empresa.X509Certificado);
                wsProxy.Betha = new Betha();
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.THEMA:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.CANOAS_RS:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                cabecMsg = "<cabecalho versao=\"201001\"><versaoDados>V2010</versaoDados></cabecalho>";
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.ISSNET:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.ISSONLINE:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.BLUMENAU_SC:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.BHISS:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                cabecMsg = "<cabecalho xmlns=\"http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd\" versao=\"1.00\"><versaoDados >1.00</versaoDados ></cabecalho>";
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.GIF:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.DUETO:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis, padraoNFSe);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.WEBISS:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis, padraoNFSe);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                cabecMsg = "<cabecalho xmlns=\"http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd\" versao=\"1.00\"><versaoDados >1.00</versaoDados ></cabecalho>";
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.PAULISTANA:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.SALVADOR_BA:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis, padraoNFSe);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.PORTOVELHENSE:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis, padraoNFSe);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                cabecMsg = "<cabecalho versao=\"2.00\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" xmlns=\"http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd\"><versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados></cabecalho>";
                break;

            case PadroesNFSe.PRONIN:
                wsProxy = ConfiguracaoApp.DefinirWS(Servico, empresa, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpAmb, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.tpEmis, padraoNFSe);
                pedLoteRps = wsProxy.CriarObjeto(NomeClasseWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Não foi possível detectar o padrão da NFS-e.");
        }

        if (padraoNFSe != PadroesNFSe.IPM)
        {
            //Assinar o XML
            AssinaturaDigital ad = new AssinaturaDigital();
            ad.Assinar(NomeArquivoXML, empresa, Convert.ToInt32(ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio));

            //Invocar o método que envia o XML para o SEFAZ
            oInvocarObj.InvocarNFSe(wsProxy, pedLoteRps, NomeMetodoWS(Servico, ler.oDadosPedSitNfseRps.cMunicipio, empresa.tpAmb), cabecMsg, this, "-ped-sitnfserps", "-sitnfserps", padraoNFSe, Servico, empresa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ajudaria se a pergunta fosse clara no que quer saber, no que quer fazer com ele. Poderia citar onde viu, o que não entendeu, postar um exemplo de uso que não conseguir usar, se quer fazer o funcionamento interno dele, ou outra coisa. A documentação está aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: è que na verdade eu queria saber exatamente isso, em que eu posso usar esse método, eu li esta documentação e não ficou tão claro pra mim, então gostaria de aprender onde eu posso aplicar ela, no que ela é útil e ajuda...

Comment: É que é complicado falar de algo tão abstratamente, sem um foco. Isto é usado em reflexão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101. Se você não precisa de reflexão, não precisa deste método. Se deseja ver um exemplo de uso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137542/101. É complicado? É. Por isso que precisa informar melhor o que deseja.

Comment: Esse exemplo já ajudou, mas ainda se soubermos mais detalhes sobre o que vem em `nfe` dá para responder melhor. Eu tenho uma impressão maior que esse código é gambiarra de alguém que não sabe o que está fazendo. Mas só posso afirmar com mais detalhes de como esse método é chamado. Aparentemente mais pessoas não sabem bem sobre isto já que eu tomei negativo. Acabei negativando a resposta do cigano porque ela está errada, basta ler a minha resposta pra ver os erros constantes lá. Ele até acabou apagando a dele, pena que não retirou o negativo da minha resposta.

Comment: Adicionei oque é o nfe na pergunta

Comment: Melhorei a resposta com o que adicionou agora. Realmente eu estava certo, não precisa dessa complicação toda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aconselho fortemente ler a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_InvokeMember_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_System_Reflection_Binder_System_Object_System_Object___) que tem todos os detalhes sobre o método e exemplos de uso.

Este é um método pertencente ao tipo [`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que é um tipo basicamente usado para a [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101). Este é o tipo que te dá todas informações necessárias sobre os tipos da aplicação. Ele disponibiliza tudo mesmo, como se fosse um conjunto de *arrays* de todas informações que está dentro dele. Ele mostra além do nome do tipo, os tipos herdados, os seus atributos e outras informações gerais, todos os seus membros, sejam variáveis, propriedades, métodos, etc. Você pode ver [todas informações que estão disponíveis sobre os métodos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Métodos podem ser chamados, certo? Se você [pegar todos os métodos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethods) ou [propriedades](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetProperties) ([informações das propriedades](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)) do tipo pode chamá-los sem mesmo conhecer a estrutura do que está trabalhando, você pode chamar algo que nem sabe o que é ainda enquanto está codificando.

#Seu exemplo

Me parece que este código está pegando um tipo (`tipoServico`) que foi criado dinamicamente em tempo de execução (depois descubro que não), ou seja, seu código nem sabe como ele é mesmo, e parece que ele veio de um XML que definirá sua estrutura. Provavelmente este tipo será definido assim:

```
var tipoServico = xml.GetType();
```

Eu acho que não poderia usar o `typeof` (se confirmou depois) porque para usá-lo precisaria ter as informações em tempo de compilação, o que perderia o sentido de usar o `InvokeMember()`. Só não afirmo por não ter mais informações na pergunta.

Sabe-se que existe um propriedade chamada `SalvarXmlRetornoEm` e ele vai usar o método da [propriedade que faz o *set*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Como toda propriedade só pode ser aplicada em um objeto, ele é passado para o método, no caso é um objeto chamado `xml`, como está no código. Para *setar*  uma valor para uma propriedade tem que passar um argumento, e ele é o `repositorio.xmlRetorno` que deve estar no código em algum lugar (seria melhor que tivesse todo o código). Se fosse um método poderia ter outros argumentos por isso ele aceita um *array*.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var xml = new Servico();
        var tipoServico = xml.GetType();
        tipoServico.InvokeMember("SalvarXmlRetornoEm", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, xml, new object[] { "local" });
        WriteLine(xml.SalvarXmlRetornoEm);
    }
}

//pra simplificar vou fazer um tipo em código mesmo

public class Servico {
    public string SalvarXmlRetornoEm { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jZ0mkX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkMbz7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/InvokeMember.cs).

Se sabe qual é o tipo e se sabe qual é a propriedade em tempo de compilação, pra que fazer isto? Talvez o código tenha sido escrito por alguém que não sabe o que está fazendo.

#Simplificando o código

O mecanismo de reflexão não é necessário neste caso. É raro ele ser necessário, exceto em *frameworks* que precisam automatizar tarefas internas que poderiam ser feitas com código normal, mas com muito mais trabalho, ou se precisar realizar algo só conhecido em tempo de execução. Não é o caso, a reflexão só piora este código.

Reforço o que eu comecei escrevendo na resposta: se você sabe o nome dos membros que deseja acessar não tem porque usar reflexão. Cito em especial `pegar todos os métodos ou propriedades`. Se você vai pegar um específico já sabe o nome dele e não precisa de reflexão.

Não vou criticar o seu uso aí porque poucas pessoas entendem o uso de reflexão e que [genericidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) costuma ser um mecanismo muito melhor. Pra falar a verdade acho que nem precisa ser genérico, pode ser o [polimórfico tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101). Não sei se precisaria mudar em mais algum lugar, talvez tenha que virtualizar as propriedades da `TaskAbst` (nome fora de padrão). Sem virtualizar, só funciona com genéricos.

Daria muito trabalho para eu reescrever aqui na resposta todo o código para ficar genérico ou polimórfico em vez de reflexivo, que é mais seguro e performático, mas daria para fazer alguma coisa assim:

```
private void EnviarArquivo(Empresa empresa, string arquivoXmlEnvio, string localSalvarXmlRetorno, TaskAbst nfe) {
    nfe.NomeArquivoXML = arquivoXmlEnvio;
    nfe.SalvarXmlRetornoEm =  localSalvarXmlRetorno;
    nfe.Execute();
}
```

Tem como fazer o parâmetro `metodo` mas daria um pouco mais de trabalho e acrescentaria um complicador. Inclusive uma forma seria passar a própria variável `servico` do `switch` para definir o que chamar, se precisar mesmo. Eu nem conseguiria adaptar porque não tem documentação ou exemplo de uso como usar esse parâmetro. Acho que ele nem é necessário.

Obviamente que tudo o que o chama terá que ser mudado para chamar da forma correta, vou pegar um exemplo do `switch` na mesma classe só pra exemplificar:

```
CertVencido(empresa);
IsConnectedToInternet();
switch (servico) {
    case Servicos.ConsultarLoteRps:
        EnviarArquivo(empresa, arquivoXmlEnvio, localSalvarXmlRetorno, new TaskConsultarLoteRps());
        break;
    ...
```

Note que eu já dei uma simplificada no código. Eu vi uma quantidade enorme de problemas nessa e em outras classes, ou seja, o código é muito mal escrito. Sendo bem sincero, sem papas na língua, é trágico. Reconheço o esforço de quem fez, mas ele não é bom, apesar que deve ajudar muita gente e isto tem mérito.

Nem isso seria necessário. Nem o `switch` precisaria ser usado. O polimorfismo poderia ser adotado para alcançar o objetivo, o que seria um uso de orientação a objeto benéfico, ao contrário da maioria do código dito OOP que as pessoas pessoas fazem que não serve para nada útil.

Comment: Adicionei uma parte mais completa do código, é pq estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para emissão de NFSe e estou usando a lib NFSE.NET que se encontra no github como exemplo, e me deparei com este método rs... no ultimo trecho de código que coloquei na pergunta ha na ultima linha um (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod), este seria para invocar um método já criado? se puder me ajudar a entender esta parte também eu agradeço rsrs...