# Criando um dicionário com funções void

Tags: c#, .net, funções, tipagem, dicionário

Estou por diversão a desenvolver um servidor de TCP em C# que executa funções dependendo da mensagem que o cliente conectado lhe envia, para já, apenas consegui fazer o que pretendo com funções que retornam strings, para tal tenho o seguinte:

Um dicionário que armazena a *string* da mensagem que é suposto o utilizador enviar para o servidor de forma a que seja executada a função que ele deseja e a função em questão:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<string>> stringFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();
```

Uma função que procura a função que o cliente quer:

```
private string CheckCommands() {
    for(int i = 0; i < stringFunctions.Count; i++)
        if(stringFunctions.ContainsKey(rcvString))
            return stringFunctions[rcvString].Invoke();
    return "";
}
```

Realização da procura dentro do loop da comunicação com o cliente:

```
string commandAnswer = CheckCommands();
if(commandAnswer != "") {
    netStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commandAnswer), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commandAnswer).Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", commandAnswer);
} else {
    netStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Could not find that command in our database"), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Could not find that command in our database").Length);
}
```

Como coloco a função no dicionário:

```
myFunctions.Add("test", new Func<string>(Test));
```

Isto tudo que apresentei funciona, mas queria agora conseguir usar o mesmo método mas para funções void, existe alguma forma parecida com o que tento fazer? Ainda não consegui chegar lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar o mesmo método, se eu entendi, não é possível porque o método que escreveu espera trabalhar com uma função que retorna uma `string`.

Na verdade seu dicionário só aceita funções com a mesma assinatura, ou seja, sem parâmetros e com o retorno do tipo `string`. Para manter a mesma linha teria que usar outros dicionários com outras assinaturas, por exemplo para fazer oque quer:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action>> voidFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

E aí um método que analisa e chama a função sem retorno.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se realmente quiser colocar tudo no mesmo dicionário terá que fazer algo assim:

```
private Dictionary<string, dynamic> functions = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
```

ou

```
private Dictionary<string, object>> functions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/DynamicObject.cs).

E o seu método que manda executar a função deve usar como retorno o [`dynamic` ou `object`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101) também.

Só que aí vale pôr qualquer coisa ali e pra ficar robusto teria que controlar o que adiciona para ter certeza que é uma função e na hora de chamar também terá que rotear corretamente, ou seja, é bem mais complicado.

Tem inúmeras outras formas de fazer, mas tem que pensar em vários aspectos, a decisão não é simples, não dá para dizer o que é bom sem conhecer detalhes. E nenhuma será simples, a não ser que faça de forma ingênua, frágil e até insegura.

Para dar um exemplo, pode usar o [sistema de *scripts*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101) para chamar a função. Eu não sou um grande fã disso, pode ser bem inseguro, mas é para ilustrar que tem opções e cada uma tem sua desvantagens.

O uso de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101) pode ser o caminho mais adequado em muitos casos. Em alguns casos o uso de um gerador de código pode simplificar muita coisa.

Para alguns casos, mas não todos, poderia ter uma indireção extra que lineariza o uso de todas funções.

Comment: Sim eu sei que o meu dicionário só aceita funções string, queria apenas saber como alterar de forma a que desse outro tipo de funções como explicou mais à frente. Já agora, nos seus excertos de código continua a chamar um dicionário do tipo <string, Func<string>>. De qualquer forma obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Comment: è, eu esqueci de trocar nos dois locais.